# How can i run java applications in docker using apache or tomcat server

Tags: java, docker

I am new to docker. I want to run my java application on tomcat server using docker images/containers. Can anyone suggest best method to do that?

Answer (score 3):

First find a docker image with the version of tomcat you want. You can search docker images using, `docker search` so try

```
docker search tomcat
```

next pull it locally

```
docker pull <your/image>
```

then run commands on it to install your software

```
docker run <your/image> <your command and args>
```

then find your container ID by running

```
docker images
```

and commit you changes

```
docker commit <container_id> <some_name>
```

I'd recommend the [docker tutorial](https://www.docker.com/tryit/) to get started.

P.S. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24805696/368186) will show you how to transfer files to docker.