# How can I add a volume to an existing Docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker container that I've created simply by installing Docker on Ubuntu and doing:

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I immediately started installing Java and some other tools, spent some time with it, and stopped the container by

```
exit
```

Then I wanted to add a volume and realised that this is not as straightforward as I thought it would be. If I use `sudo docker -v /somedir run ...` then I end up with a fresh new container, so I'd have to install Java and do what I've already done before just to arrive at a container with a mounted volume.

All the documentation about mounting a folder from the host seems to imply that mounting a volume is something that can be done when creating a container. So the only option I have to avoid reconfiguring a new container from scratch is to commit the existing container to a repository and use that as the basis of a new one whilst mounting the volume.

Is this indeed the only way to add a volume to an existing container?

Comment: Not sure if that helps but when I did `docker exec -it d1a2cc990208 bash` from the same location, I was in the container with the mounted volume.

Answer (score 699, accepted):

You can commit your existing container (that creates a new image from container’s changes) and then run it with your new mounts.

Example:

```bash
$ docker ps  -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
5a8f89adeead        ubuntu:14.04          "/bin/bash"              About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                       agitated_newton

$ docker commit 5a8f89adeead newimagename
$ docker run -ti -v "$PWD/somedir":/somedir newimagename /bin/bash
```

If it's all OK, stop your old container, and use this new one.

You can also commit a container using its name, for example:

```
docker commit agitated_newton newimagename
```

That's it :)

Comment: And if you need the new container to take the old name for some reason, use [docker rename](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rename/) after removing the old one.

Comment: just wanted to point out that above where you mention `newnameofcontainer` that this should probably be named `new_image_name` -- because `docker commit` creates a new *image* on your system. Then in the following when you do a `docker run` you actually use the name of the *image* that you want to run a new container from. The above works but just wanted to clarify for others that the placeholder newnameofcontainer above is actually the name for a new image. thanks! awesome answer. oh, you can see the newly created image from the first docker commit command using `docker image ls`

Comment: In fact, you don't need commit a new container if you want to start from a image.
Just `docker run -v /srv/a:/tmp ubuntu:14.04` is good.

Comment: I already have a container running with all files. if the above method creates new container, i can not build everything from once again. Is there a way i can avoid this and mount without having to create new container or image?

Comment: Will this keep the old volume mappings from the old container or should I re-declare them with the new container also?

Comment: @YongHaoHu nice idea! But is it not dangerous to put it in `/tmp`? i.e. the contents will get wiped when you stop your container?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă Perhaps when you [*start*](https://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared) the container.

Comment: This won't preserve processes running in the original container.

Comment: Commiting container won't keep volume bindings, any solution for that?

Comment: I run docker on windows server 2019 that does not support commit of a running container , what is the equivalent command to use in windows?

Comment: Committing saves the container as an image without the volume bindings. Any new container created from that image will need to have all the desired volume bindings re-listed when it is created. All committing saves is the internal state of the container.

Comment: I wonder when using `docker run -ti --name containername -v "$PWD/somedir":/somedir imagename /bin/bash` to create and run a container `containername`. If it is stopped, after start it with `docker start containername` then attach with `docker attach containername`. Will the `-v "$PWD/somedir":/somedir imagename` parameter still persists?

Answer (score 186):

We don't have any way to add volume in running container, but to achieve this objective you may use the below commands:

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem:

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH

docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH CONTAINER:DEST_PATH
```

For reference see:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: There's a huge difference between mounting a volume and copying files to and from a container...

Comment: Anyway it helped me. I didn't know 'docker cp' command, and was trying to achieve exactly this - copy files from running container to the host.

Comment: it's not a mount, but it's handy to bring files back and froth between container and local host.

Comment: While this does solve the problem of replicating container contents locally, this is not close to being equivalent to mounting a volume and shouldn't be thought of as an alternative. Namely, replication has to be managed by the user, and the data exists now in two places.

Comment: I don't understand why so many up votes, this is a very wrong answer for the question asked.

Comment: This indeed not exactly the OP's case but I came here looking for a way to attach volume to a *running* container. My goal was to get some content in/out of a container on the fly while it's running; assuming I do not control container creation and there is no option of stopping it. This answer actually points out the only way of achieving this. So, +1 and Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned there is no support to add volume in running container, I think that's closest answer. In our case we don't want to replicate apache htdocs and mysql database setup process again, Steps:

1) Create a new duplicate container with desired volumes
2) Copy related folders to new container 
3) Remove old container -f

Comment: The thing we're trying to mount may be a socket or other device so this answer falls a little short being of a full solution because it only applies to things that can be copied with a docker cp command.

Comment: I think this is a practical answer. If you're trying to add a volume to a container, you can copy the data out of the container into the folder that will be used for the volume, and then you can simply remove and re-create the container and it'll pull in the data from that volume folder. Worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 117):

I've successfully mount `/home/<user-name>` folder of my host to the `/mnt` folder of the existing (not running) container. You can do it in the following way:

1. Open configuration file corresponding to the stopped container, which can be found at `/var/lib/docker/containers/99d...1fb/config.v2.json` (may be `config.json` for older versions of docker).
2. Find `MountPoints` section, which was empty in my case: `"MountPoints":{}`. Next replace the contents with something like this (you can copy proper contents from another container with proper settings):

```
"MountPoints":{"/mnt":{"Source":"/home/<user-name>","Destination":"/mnt","RW":true,"Name":"","Driver":"","Type":"bind","Propagation":"rprivate","Spec":{"Type":"bind","Source":"/home/<user-name>","Target":"/mnt"},"SkipMountpointCreation":false}}
```

or the same (formatted):

```json
  "MountPoints": {
    "/mnt": {
      "Source": "/home/<user-name>",
      "Destination": "/mnt",
      "RW": true,
      "Name": "",
      "Driver": "",
      "Type": "bind",
      "Propagation": "rprivate",
      "Spec": {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/home/<user-name>",
        "Target": "/mnt"
      },
      "SkipMountpointCreation": false
    }
  }
```

3. Restart the docker service: `service docker restart`

This works for me with Ubuntu 18.04.1 and Docker 18.09.0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Step 3 is crucial. I would also add that it's better to stop the docker container first before doing the write.

Comment: This is the best answer as it totally preserves the existing container.
This is what I did:
1. Stop the docker engine: `systemctl stop docker.service`
2. Edit `config.v2.json`: `vim <(jq . /var/lib/docker/containers/<container-ID>/config.v2.json)`
3. Save updates to a file: `:w config.v2.json`
4. Exit vim: `:q!`
5. Update existing file: `jq -c . config.v2.json > /var/lib/docker/containers/<container-ID>/config.v2.json`
6. Start the docker engine: `systemctl start docker.service`
7. Start the container if necessary: `docker start <container-name/ID>`
8. Enjoy :-)

Comment: **A key step** is `service docker restart`. I tried to `docker restart <container>` then the new config is not picked up, and it's getting overwritten by the old config.

Comment: Also `jq` will help pretty print the JSON so it's mroe human editable: `cat config.v2.json | jq . > config.json`

Comment: Amazing! Easy to follow and don't need to worry about losing files. Works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems I cannot find the `config.v2.json` by the container id in Docker version 20.10.7

Comment: It seems it doesn't work (2023/01), after restarting `config.v2.json` is restored back to the original state (without new mount point).

Comment: @jnemecz Did you **restart** the **docker** service itself, not the Container?

Comment: Unable to make this work with Docker 24.0.6. Same as @jnemecz, changes are reverted. I stopped containers, stopped service, made edits, restarted service, restarted containers.

Comment: Completely works as advertised with `dockerd` `v20.10.7`, esp. @AndroidControl's [procedure](/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container#comment98804407_53516263).

Comment: but restart docker will stop and restart all process in all containers, I hope I can add a mount point on a running container

Answer (score 31):

[Jérôme Petazzoni](https://github.com/jpetazzo) has a pretty interesting blog post on how to [Attach a volume to a container while it is running](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/). This isn't something that's built into Docker out of the box, but possible to accomplish.

As he also points out

> This will not work on filesystems which are not based on block devices.
>
> It will only work if /proc/mounts correctly lists the block device node (which, as we saw above, is not necessarily true).
>
> Also, I only tested this on my local environment; I didn’t even try on a cloud instance or anything like that

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately the switch option to mount a volume is only found in the `run` command.

`docker run --help`

`-v, --volume    list Bind mount a volume (default [])`

There is a way you can work around this though so you won't have to reinstall the applications you've already set up on your container.

1. Export your container
   `docker container export -o ./myimage.docker mycontainer`
2. Import as an image
   `docker import ./myimage.docker myimage`
3. Then `docker run -i -t -v /somedir --name mycontainer myimage /bin/bash`

Comment: FYI - `docker container` isn't a valid command on 1.11.2 (which is the latest version that is supported by Synology as of this writing).  I can't find any docs saying when it was added, though.

In this case the first command is `docker export -o ./myimage.docker mycontainer`.

Comment: Using `docker commit` is much easier, see answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/33956387/1260896

Comment: This one doesn't preserve history though, so it's still a good solution for the space conscious.

Answer (score 8):

A note for using Docker Windows containers

Conditions:

- Windows 10
- Docker Desktop (latest version)
- using Docker Windows Container for image microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer

Problem:

- I wanted to mount a host dictionary into my windows container.

Solution as partially described here:

- Create docker container

`docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=<STRONG_PASSWORD> -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer`

- Go to command shell in container

`docker exec -it <CONTAINERID> cmd.exe`

- Create DIR

`mkdir DirForMount`

- Stop container

`docker container stop <CONTAINERID>`

- Commit container

`docker commit <CONTAINERID> <NEWIMAGENAME>`

- Delete old container

`docker container rm <CONTAINERID>`

- Create new container with new image and volume mounting

`docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=<STRONG_PASSWORD> -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -v C:\DirToMount:C:\DirForMount <NEWIMAGENAME>`

After this I solved this problem on docker windows containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop and remove the container, append the existing volume in a startup script, and restart from the image. If the already existing existing partitions do keep the data, you shouldn't experience any loss of information. This should also work the same way with Dockerfile and Docker composer.

eg (solr image).
**(initial script)**

```
#!/bin/sh
docker pull solr:8.5
docker stop my_solr
docker rm solr:8.5

docker create \
  --name my_solr \
  -v "/XXXX/docker/solr/solrdata":/var/solr \
  -p 8983:8983 \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  --user 1000:1000 \
  -e SOLR_HEAP=1g \
  --log-opt max-size=10m \
  --log-opt max-file=3 \
  solr:8.5
docker cp /home/XXXX/docker/solr/XXXXXXXX.jar my_solr:/opt/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/lib
docker start my_solr
```

**file with the second volume**

```
#!/bin/sh
docker pull solr:8.5
docker stop my_solr
docker rm solr:8.5

docker create \
  --name my_solr \
  -v "/XXXX/docker/solr/solrdata":/var/solr \
  -v "/XXXX/backups/solr_snapshot_folder":/var/solr_snapshots \
  -p 8983:8983 \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  --user 1000:1000 \
  -e SOLR_HEAP=1g \
  --log-opt max-size=10m \
  --log-opt max-file=3 \
  solr:8.5
docker cp /home/XXXX/docker/solr/XXXXXXXX.jar my_solr:/opt/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/lib
docker start my_solr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're under linux and have enough privileges, there's a way to attach a bind mount to a running container.
See e.g. `https://brauner.io/2023/02/28/mounting-into-mount-namespaces.html` for more info.

Here's a working example following above blog post.
The program takes 3 arguments: host directory, container directory and any pid of some program currently running in the container. To find the latter, do `ps x |grep whatever_runs_inyour_container`. It's easiest to run the program with sudo.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sched.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <linux/mount.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("usage: ./a.out pid src_dir dst_dir\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char *pid = argv[1];
    char *src_dir = argv[2];
    char *dst_dir = argv[3];

    int fd_mnt;
    fd_mnt = syscall(__NR_open_tree, 
        -EBADF, src_dir, OPEN_TREE_CLONE);

    if (fd_mnt < 0) {
        perror("open_tree failed");
        return 1;
    }

    char mount_namespace[1000];
    snprintf(mount_namespace, 1000, "/proc/%s/ns/mnt", pid);
    int fd_mntns = open(mount_namespace, O_RDONLY);

    if (fd_mntns < 0) {
        printf("open /proc/%s/ns/mnt failed: %s", pid, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    setns(fd_mntns, 0);

    int ret = syscall(__NR_move_mount, 
        fd_mnt, "", -EBADF, dst_dir, MOVE_MOUNT_F_EMPTY_PATH );

    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("move_mount failed");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("mounted %s to %s of namespace %s,", src_dir, dst_dir, mount_namespace);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use symlink to the already mounted drive:

`ln -s Source_path targer_path_which_is_already_mounted_on_the_running_docker`

Answer (score -1):

You can stop your container, add the volume and restart it. How to do it, follow the steps.

```
docker volume create ubuntu-volume
docker stop <container-name>
sudo docker run -i -t --mount source=ubuntu-volume,target=<target-path-in-container> ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: docker run creates a _new_ container from an image (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/). OP is asking about adding a volume to an _existing_ container.

Answer (score -6):

The best way is to copy all the files and folders inside a directory on your local file system by: `docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH`

`SRC_PATH` is on container
`DEST_PATH` is on localhost

Then do `docker-compose down` attach a volume to the same `DEST_PATH` and run Docker containers by using `docker-compose up -d`

Add volume by following in `docker-compose.yml`

```
volumes:
 - DEST_PATH:SRC_PATH
```

Comment: There are other, better options above.

Comment: Indeed, there are better options above, and copying files around is not mounting them. In addition, the "volumes" definition given for the docker-compose option is the other way around: 
volumes:
 - HOST_PATH:CONTAINER_PATH