# Docker reuse container but change volume

Tags: docker

Is it possible to change the volume local path?

Using Kitematic, I can do it. But I don't find the way to do it from cli.

For instance, I run docker using:
`docker run --name nodejs-environment -v $(pwd):/code -it node:9.3.0 alpine sh`

I would like to reuse the container but change the volume, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you use `docker run` it will rebuild your container. Instead use `docker exec` to run a command in an existing container. Though unfortunately, exec will not allow you to specify new volumes either. As far as I know [there is currently no way to reassign volumes in an existing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container).

Your best bet is just to rebuild the container. It doesn't take long and they are meant to be fairly disposable. Alternatively, you could use volumes to point to a parent directory with all the code you'll ever need, or just use volumes to mount both directories:

```
docker run --name nodejs-environment \
  -v $(pwd)/first_source:/first_source \
  -v $(pwd)/second_source:/second_source \
  -it node:9.3.0 alpine sh
```

---

But if you really need *exactly* this functionality, reassigning volumes after the container is already built, you could accomplish it with some hacky use of symbolic links:

```
ln -s first_source/ link 
docker run --name nodejs-environment -v $(pwd)/link:/code -it node:9.3.0 alpine sh
```

Once you have finished with the first volume, you can swap out the symbolic link:

```
rm link
ln -s second_source/ link
```

Note that if you exited the terminal from `docker run`, it will stop your container. So you would have to restart your container to exec into it again:

```
docker start nodejs-environment
docker exec -it nodejs-environment sh
```