# How to attach the volume to the existing docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, devops, docker-machine, docker-container

I've a container which is already up and running. In my container I didn't attach any volume of my host machine and it tooks the default docker volume.

Is there any way to attach the volume to my running container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a volume to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container)