# How to run docker command in Python SDK

Tags: python, docker

I am using python SDK package to run docker from python.
Here is the docker command I tried to run using python package:

```
docker run -v /c/Users/msagovac/pdf_ocr:/home/docker jbarlow83/ocrmypdf-polyglot --skip-text 0ce9d58432bf41174dde7148486854e2.pdf output.pdf
```

Here is a python code:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run('jbarlow83/ocrmypdf-polyglot', '--skip-text "0ce9d58432bf41174dde7148486854e2.pdf" "output.pdf"', "-v /c/Users/msagovac/pdf_ocr:/home/docker")
```

Error says file ot found. I am not sure where to set run options:

```
-v /c/Users/msagovac/pdf_ocr:/home/docker
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with named parameters:

```
client.containers.run(
           image='jbarlow83/ocrmypdf-polyglot', 
           command='--skip-text "0ce9d58432bf41174dde7148486854e2.pdf" "output.pdf"',
           volumes={'/c/Users/msagovac/pdf_ocr': {'bind': '/home/docker', 'mode': 'rw'}},
          )
```

Also it seems that the path of the volume to mount is incorrect, try with `C:/Users/msagovac/pdf_ocr`

Comment: I works. How to include `-v ` option after `docker run`?

Comment: After run? I think you can mount a volume to container after it started running https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container

Comment: the -v option is the parameter `volumes`