# Docker: how to map to a directory on a running instance?

Tags: docker

I run Joomla image with :

```
 docker run --name some-joomla --link test-mysql:mysql -p 8080:80 -d joomla
```

How can I change Joomla files ?

I think it is possible when specifying volume mapping, but I did not use that to run Joomla: is there a way to access Joomla files now ?

Comment: you want to browse inside the container? you can use `docker exec -it some-joomla bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container) thread should help you out.

1. Commit your container and create a new image from it.
2. Run a container from your just created image (and add the volume you need). Watch out for the port mappings, you either have to use other ports temporarily to check functionality of your new container, or you do step 3 beforehand.
3. If all works out, stop the old one.

If you want to check what's currently in the container, you can jump into it by running `docker exec -it some-joomla bash` (or `sh`, whatever Shell is installed in this image). You can then look for the files you want inside the container.

If you found them and you want to copy them on your local machine, you can run `docker cp some-joomla:/your/path /path/on/local/machine`.

Comment: My question is: how to modify files in this instance: where are they stored on my linux server ?

Comment: I updated my answer, please check if you can go from there.