# Docker: How to change mountpoint of volumes?

Tags: docker

I have a web application running in container. 
The application allows users to upload files. These files are stored in Docker volumes `web_data1` and `web_data2`.

Due to changes in the application, **I need to change the mountpoint of these volumes** i.e. 
the data that were in `/srv/app/web_data1_mountpoint`, now need to be moved to `/srv/app/web_data1_changed_mountpoint`.

**What is the proper way to do this?**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  web_data1:
  web_data2:

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: web-image
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - web_data1:/srv/app/web_data1_mountpoint
      - web_data2:/srv/app/web_data2_mountpoint
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends a bit of the image you are using. Just changing the volume would work in your docker-compose.yml like this:

```
volumes:
      - web_data1:/srv/app/web_data1_changed_mountpoint
      - web_data2:/srv/app/web_data2_changed_mountpoint
```

But I dont know, what your image does with the directory. Maybe something inside the image depends on the directory.

Comment: I thought that changing the mountpoint like this would create a new volume and therefore my data would get lost. Is that wrong?

Comment: Just tested it with a local installation - your web_data1/web_data2 should stay persistent and would get mounted to the new mountpoint in your service.
Alternatively you can mount your directory inside the container to a real directory on your host-system.

Also you can add an extra mount to be sure:

- web_data1:/srv/app/web_data1_mountpoint
- web_data1:/srv/app/web_data1_changed_mountpoint