# docker: make folder of running container persistent

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In `docker-compose.yml` we are able to define persistent volumes:

```
volumes:
  -foo:bar
```

For this to work, the container has to be rebuild.

Now I need to "save" the data on a non-persistent folder in a running container. Is there a way to do this.

Can I add a persistent volume to an existing and mounted container?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a volume to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container)