# How to add volume mount to running postgreSQL container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a running postgreSQL docker container and need to add a volume mount.

I followed the steps from [How can I add a volume to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container), (ran `docker commit` on the container to save it as an image, and spun up another container based on that image with a named volume mounted in). All the data files from the first container are present in /var/lib/postgres/data of the second container.

However, when I try to query this second postgres database, I cannot see any tables that are in the first container. Been trying to fix this for a few days with no luck, am I missing something here (does mounting a volume obscure the existing data in /var/lib/postres/data)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commit will not work as there is the [volume defined in the Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/4c2e78c234a8e4293a5d6bb6a4d20421236d98d8/13/Dockerfile).

> Volumes are useful in many cases, for example, for running
> database-storage. However, since volumes are not 'part' of a
> container, it makes containers no longer portable - which seems in
> direct conflict with the slogan "Build once... Run anywhere.."

[docker commit data container with VOLUME](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6999#issuecomment-48961498)

One option that you can try is copying data folder to host from an existing container and then launch the container with mount path.

```
docker cp my_db_cotainer:/var/lib/postgresql/data  db_data
```

then start a new container with this path so it will contain the same data as the previous one

```
docker run -d --name some-postgres -v $PWD/db_data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

same for mysql

```
docker cp some-mysql-old:/var/lib/mysql db_backup
docker run --rm --name some-mysql-new -v $PWD/db_backup:/var/lib/mysql  -it mysql
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much! Still not too clear how it worked though. I see that volume is define in the Dockerfile, but it seems like both what I was doing and what you suggested mounted the data into /var/lib/postgresql/data, what is the difference?

Comment: in the simple word, volume is not part of docker commit , so when mount  directory it hide  what inside docker and host files.