# How do I attach a volume to a running container starting from the Docker Run command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-volume

I need to attach a volume to the running container which has started from the docker run command on my AWS EC2 server (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) with the following command

```
$ docker run --name example -p 8080:80 -dt example-image:latest
```

I'm using Docker version 19.03.12.

Comment: You have to delete and recreate the container with a new `docker run` command.  Note that you need to do this for many other common tasks too (especially running the container with a newer image) and I'd treat this as totally routine.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container/56970321#56970321