# Arangodump backup to a USB drive from within a docker container?

Tags: docker, arangodb, ubuntu-21.04

I'm running ArangoDB version 3.8.0 in a docker container on my primary drive on Ubuntu 21.04.

That drive is unfortunately full, and I can't clear enough data to make a backup.

I have the folder `/dumps` in the container mapped to a place on that drive, `/media/m/Data/`.

I do however have a USB drive with enough space to store the backup, but I can't figure out how to get Arango to dump to a harddrive connected via USB. I believe the answer will involve mapping the drive to somewhere in the docker container, but I don't know enough about how docker works to solve this on my own.

Things tried:

Set `arangodumps` output directory to `/dev/fd/1` -> `FATAL {dump} cannot write to output directory /dev/fd/1`

Changed the mapping of the drive in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` -> container disappeared, thought I lost the data and panicked a little. Changed it back and everything was okay.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a mount to your running container. However you can do as described here:
[How can I add a volume to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container)

- Commit your container
- Run the new image with added mount
- Check if the container has all your changes make you dump in this container

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this problem by installing arango on another machine on the same network with the USB drive and ran:

```
arangodump --output-directory <Mounted USB drive> --server.endpoint <local IP:8529 of the over-full computer>
```

And it dumped to the USB drive!