# How to run command with docker that saves data on local machine

Tags: python, django, linux, docker

My intention is to dump data from Django app (running inside docker container) directly on the disk and not inside the container.
Any ideas how to do it?
I tried this:

```
docker exec -it app bash -c "python manage.py dumpdata > data.json"
```

but the data is saved inside container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect output of `docker` command, not `python`.

```
docker exec -it app bash -c "python manage.py dumpdata" > data.json
```

UPD: if `manage.py` is in working directory you can also omit `bash` invocation:

```
docker exec -it app python manage.py dumpdata > data.json
```

Answer (score 3):

**First**, run your container with the [-v option](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/):

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/data-out <app-image>
```

This will map your current directory (pwd) to the container's `/data-out` dir (it will create this dir inside the container if it doesn't exist). You can change `$(pwd)` to `/something/else` if you want.

**Second**, execute your command:

```
docker exec -it app bash -c "python manage.py dumpdata > /data-out/data.json"
```

Notice that the  output goes to the `data-out` dir.

**Finally**, view your file locally:

```
cat data.json
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton, I guess there isn't a way without stopping/starting the docker container?

Comment: @cristian see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

You can use a volume parameter with the docker run command:

```
docker run -v /app/logs:/app/logs ...
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#volume

Comment: This is correct in that volumes are a good way to keep a container's data accessible in relatively simple ways, but the question implies that a container already exists and we want to get the data it already has.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a volume when running docker run

```
docker exec -it app bash -c "python manage.py dumpdata > /data/data.json" -v $pwd:/data
```

Comment: I don't think docker exec hast the mount option though.