# Copy multiple files in docker with cp

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I want to transfer multiple files from ubuntu to a docker container. For single file, the below command works:

```
docker cp file_name CONTAINER:path/
```

But I am not able to upload multiple files at once. I have tried following commands, but no success yet:

```
docker cp {file1,file2} CONTAINER:path/
docker cp [file1,file2] CONTAINER:path/
docker cp ["file1","file2"] CONTAINER:path/
```

All above commands returns "no such file or directory" error

Comment: in the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/ they say `SRC_PATH specifies a file `  or `SRC_PATH specifies a directory ` Maybe put all your files in a folder and copy the folder?

Comment: Folder move is working fine. But uploading whole folder is not required every time. Is there any command where I can upload multiple files selectively?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, no. At the moment, `docker cp` lacks some improvements

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939419/copying-file-from-host-to-container?rq=1

Comment: and https://github.com/WhisperingChaos/dkrcp

Comment: you can use some with netcat like `one trick I used recently to avoid restarting the container was netcat "nc"

in the container: nc -l 10101 > thefile.bin
on the host: cat thefile.bin | nc 172.0.2.3 10101
(where 172.0.2.3 is the container ip, and 10101 is a random port of your choosing)` from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/905

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$ tar Ccf $(dirname SRC_PATH) - $(basename SRC_PATH) | docker exec -i foo tar Cxf DEST_PATH -
```

Using `-` as the `SRC_PATH` streams the contents of STDIN as a `tar archive`. The command extracts the content of the tar to the `DEST_PATH` in container’s filesystem. In this case, `DEST_PATH` must specify a directory. Using `-` as the `DEST_PATH` streams the contents of the resource as a tar archive to STDOUT.

You can read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).