# How to add files to an existing docker image?

Tags: docker

I have a windows-based docker container, run it and run an app inside it. But sometimes I need to add a folder to the image and run another app.
How can I add recursively

```
\folder
 folder\*.*
\subfolder1
 subfolder1\*.*
\subfolder2
 subfolder2\*.*
```

from my host machine to my image?

Comment: Can you build a derived image `FROM` the original image, `COPY`ing in the new files?  Or use a bind mount when you launch the container?

Comment: same question once more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939419/docker-copying-file-from-host-to-container

Comment: another once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/docker-copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/):

> The docker cp utility copies the contents of SRC_PATH to the DEST_PATH. You can copy from the container’s file system to the local machine or the reverse, from the local filesystem to the container.

```sh
docker cp /path/to/dir mycontainer:/path/in/container/
```

> The cp command behaves like the Unix cp -a command in that directories are copied recursively with permissions preserved if possible.

Furthermore, as stated in the docs, if this is not feasible, you can use some hacks with tar like below.

```sh
tar Ccf $(dirname SRC_PATH) - $(basename SRC_PATH) | docker exec -i CONTAINER tar Cxf DEST_PATH -
```

Comment: Any changes you make this way will be lost as soon as the container exits.

Comment: Not, if you use commit.

Comment: `docker commit` creates an image that you can't recreate when there's a mandatory critical security update in a year.  It's really not a best practice at all.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But it's still possible. I personally wouldn't do it either. I still see use cases for it. Maybe to save something critical to the business, because someone didn't follow best practices in the first place. Maybe docker CP can also be useful for debugging and development. Normally I would use it to get default configs out of the container but, hey, you never know what people are up to.

Comment: I run the docker, it is active, >docker ps shows it, then trying to run PS D:\> docker cp d:/mc myxxx:c:/app/mc/
Error response from daemon: filesystem operations against a running Hyper-V container are not supported