# Creating a Docker container with runnable android tool

Tags: linux, docker, android-source

I have a Linux machine where I successfully built the Android Open Source Project (AOSP).
One of the products of this build is `grxmlcompile` (in /aosp/out/host/Linux-x86/bin), which is the tool I need.
I would like to create a `Docker` container that has a runnable version of `grxmlcompile`.

I'm a beginner Docker user, and I can't seem to make it work.
What is the right way to do it? Do I need to compile it in the container?

**UPDATE:**
I have created a container from the ubuntu:14.04 image and struggled with getting the file into it. Finally used the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container), but couldn't run the file. I'm not sure if it's a permission issue, or the file is not runnable.

Comment: Though you didn't tell us about your actual errors: please check if there might be 32-bit vs 64-bit issues. In my experience I needed to install some support libraries for 32-bit. Using the official ubuntu:14.04 Docker image will only support 64-bit.