# "docker cp" all files from a folder to existing container folder

Tags: docker

Am I missing something when I try to copy files from one folder to a existing container folder:

[Doc](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cp/)

I want to copy files within the build(host) folder to html in my container:

```
docker cp ./src/build b081dbbb679b:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

To be clear; I need to copy from host to container.

But it copies the whole build folder and copies it to ..html/build

I just need the files(and sub folders) within the build folder to be copied into ..html.

Am I missing something or do I have to copy each file one by one?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Here is the explanation from [the doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description) on how to use the `cp` command in docker, which will fix your issue with `/.` at the end of `SRC_PATH`:

> - `SRC_PATH` does not end with `/.` (that is: *slash* followed by *dot*)
>
>   - the source directory is copied into this directory
> - `SRC_PATH` does end with `/.` (that is: *slash* followed by *dot*)
>
>   - the *content* of the source directory is copied into this directory

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows.
"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: Note here that `/.` is not just a full stop at the end of OPs sentence, might be obvious to some. It has to have `/.` at the end of the src path to copy all the files from the directory but not the directory itself.

Answer (score 71):

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem is like below formats:

- Copy file to folder inside container:

  ```
  docker cp ./src/build/index.html ContainerName:/app/
  ```

  above example shows `index.html` file is copying to `app` folder inside container
- Copy all files to folder inside container:

  ```
  docker cp ./src/build/. ContainerName:/app/
  ```

  above example shows all files inside `build` folder are copying to `app` folder inside container

Comment: It's possible copy a format file?, e.g. docker cp ./src/build/*.txt ContainerName:/app/

Comment: Notice to the [Docker cp command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp), there isn't any command for your intention

Comment: @ambigus9 One possible solution is to move all the similar type of files in a directory inside the container, and then copy you can copy that folder using *docker cp*

Comment: @Nabin could be a solution! Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Just use "." (Dot - instead of "*" in Linux) after your file path, it will copy entire files from the folder

<s>docker cp /file/path/* containerId:/filepath/nginx/html/</s>

```
docker cp /file/path/. containerId:/filepath/nginx/html/
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you can iterate through all txt files in a folder and copy them into the container with this command:

```
for /r %i in (*.txt) do docker cp %i containerId:/blabla/bla/
```