# Issues with creating a containerised Next.js + Flask + PostgreSQL application

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose, next.js

## Problem:

I've been trying to containerise my application consisting of a Next.js frontend, Flask backend and PostgreSQL database but I've been having a lot of problems. The main issue right now is that my PostgreSQL schema is not being loaded up correctly.

#### Directory Structure:

```
|-- docker-compose.yaml
|-- backend
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   `-- app.py
|-- database
|   |-- 01-schema.sql
|   |-- 02-init.sql
|   `-- Dockerfile
`-- frontend
    |-- Dockerfile
    `-- (...Next.js App Files)
```

#### `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./database/1-schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-schema.sql
      - ./database/2-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/02-init.sql

volumes:
  data:
```

#### SQL Scripts:

`01-schema.sql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
);
```

`02-init.sql`

```sql
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ("John Doe");
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ("Jane Doe");
```

#### `app.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask
import psycopg2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api")
def index():
    conn = psycopg2.connect("postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/postgres")

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users;")
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    return result
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error message:

`psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-schema.sql: error: could not read from input file: Is a directory`

`exited with code 1`

And here is the full output:

[Output-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TExl.png)
[Output-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdZOd.png)

Then when I try to access the results of my query in `app.py`, by going to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api` I get an error saying the relation doesn't exist:

[Flask Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPtIv.png)

The database successfully received the query but also says the relation doesn't exist:

`ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist at character 15`

`STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM users;`

## Answer:

Below is the working configuration for my project.

Directory Structure:

```
|-- .env
|-- docker-compose.yaml
|-- backend
|   |-- .env
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- app.py
|   `-- dependencies.txt
|-- database
|   |-- 01-schema.sql
|   |-- 02-init.sql
|   `-- Dockerfile
`-- frontend
    |-- Dockerfile
    `-- (...Next.js App Files)
```

#### `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build: ./frontend
    image: node:18-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    image: flask:2.2.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/backend
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy

  database:
    container_name: database
    build: ./database
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    healthcheck:
      test:
        ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "${POSTGRES_USER}", "-d", "${POSTGRES_DB}"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

volumes:
  data: null
```

#### Flask Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.2-slim-buster

WORKDIR /backend

ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_DEBUG 1

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY dependencies.txt .
COPY .env .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r dependencies.txt --no-cache-dir

COPY . .

CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

#### Database Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:15.2-alpine

COPY ./*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

#### Frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Uncomment for production build
# RUN npm install --omit=dev
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

#### `.env` File:

```
POSTGRES_DB=docker
POSTGRES_USER=docker
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
POSTGRES_HOST=database
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

#### `app.py`:

```py
import psycopg2

# Note: I loaded the environment variables using python-dotenv
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database=env.POSTGRES_DB,
    user=env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password=env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    host=env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port=env.POSTGRES_PORT,
)

cur = conn.cursor()
...
```

#### `dependencies.txt`:

```
flask
psycopg2-binary
python-dotenv
```

Build the containers using `docker-compose up --build` and reset using `docker-compose down --volumes`. Start the containers using `docker-compose up`.

## Lingering Issues

1. I did not manage to get hot reloading to work for the frontend without using yarn which broke some things.
2. I couldn't figure out how to get the `.env` file from the main directory into the container for the backend using `COPY` in the Dockerfile so I just made a manual copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit should be this part of your compose file:

```yaml
volumes:
  - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  - ./database/1-schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-schema.sql
  - ./database/2-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/02-init.sql
```

As [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950494/5525527) also says, if the file you're trying to mount does not exist, docker will create an empty directory inside the container, and so that error message with "is a directory".

Please verify that the file exists, the path is right and also try to replace the relative path with an absolute path. If that doesn't work either, try mounting the entire directory, like this:

```yaml
  - ./database/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I've tried replacing the relative path with poth ${PWD} and the actual absolute path to no avail. I've also tried mounting the entire directory but that also doesn't work. As for if the file exists or not, could you check the image attached above for my directory structure? I believe everything is in the correct place but I could be wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you try adding them in the dockerfile, to see if they would work in that way? Also, migrations should be embedded in the image and not mounted at runtime in general.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Adding them in the dockerfile ended up working. I'll update my question with the answer in case anyone is having the same problem. I'm not sure what you mean by migrations being embedded in the image? Are you talking about init.sql? If so, I am only using it for development purposes and it won't be used in production. Thanks again.