# Docker cp Path not specified

Tags: docker, copy

I trying copy a folder to my container but not working. If I try

```
sudo docker cp 4aefd670e41f:/var/www/html/web2015 /home/desarrollo3/proyectos/web2015
```

The folder web2015 copy correct but I need copy the folder in my container.

**Working ok**

```
sudo docker cp 4aefd670e41f:/var/www/html/web2015 /home/desarrollo3/proyectos/web2015
```

**Not Working**

```
sudo docker cp /home/desarrollo3/proyectos/web2015 4aefd670e41f:/var/www/html/web2015
```

**Aditional info Docker**

```
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

**I've Ubuntu 15**

**The error FATA[0000] Error: Path not specified**

```
sudo docker cp /home/desarrollo3/proyectos/web2015 4aefd670e41f:/var/www/html/web2015
```

If I write this, I don't get errors but not copy nothing:

```
sudo docker cp ./folder:web2015 4aefd670e41f:/var/www/html/
```

Comment: Why don't you put a trailing '/' as specified in docker cp?

Comment: Does docker version really return 1.6.2? That sounds ancient.

Comment: I have edited the answer: that bug has been fixed since 1.6.2

Comment: Thanks!! I am very grateful. I upgraded the docker and now all its ok.

Comment: In sum: Version 1.6.2 doesn't allow copying from host to container, you need to upgrade to at least 1.8 for that support. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397831/docker-cp-error-path-not-specified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a folder that you need to copy, make sure `SRC_PATH` ends with `/` (considering `DEST_PATH` on the container does exist already)

```
sudo docker cp /home/desarrollo3/proyectos/web2015/ 4aefd670e41f:/var/www/html/web2015
```

[docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) mentions:

> `SRC_PATH` does end with `/`.
>
> the content of the source directory is copied into this directory.

As shown in [issue 13171](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/13171#issuecomment-113670771), the error message "Error: Path not specified" was fixed in docker 1.8.0 ([commit 5e86b81](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/5e86b818ed41c4dfd90624b43b5e4da29e39d653)).
Docker 1.6.2 is way too old.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error is the same. Regards.

Comment: @JordiSalom the error? Which error? Do you see an error message? What version of docker are you using? Are you on Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 3):

You can't copy to a container using "docker cp" in older dockers. If you desperately need to do it for whatever reason:

```
docker exec container touch /myfile
sudo find /var/lib/docker -iname myfile
```

This will show you where the your container filesystem is. Just cp your file here normally.

```
sudo cp -r /myfiles/webapp /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/019283091823081027401720473a2c7ff637a6f09edab6/var/www/localhost/htdocs
```

I'm not sure why Docker doesn't officially actually do this, but I suspect that there is some checksum on each layer, so if you re-use the image in another Dockerfile it might not work. But it should at least work for the lifetime of the container, so you can do what you need to.

Which hopefully for you includes updating or replacing this server soon.