# Docker cp error: Path not specified

Tags: docker, cp

I want to copy a file from my Ubuntu host to Docker container.

I use Docker 1.6.2 from 14.04 LTS repository.

When I try to copy I get error:

```
sudo docker cp 1.JPG evil_sammet:/root/openface/training-images/misha/1.jpg
FATA[0000] Error: Path not specified
```

With equal success, I can type gibberish instead of file name and path:

```
sudo docker cp sdfsdfasd dfsdffd 
FATA[0000] Error: Path not specified
```

Comment: did you try `sudo docker cp ./1.JPG evil_sammet:/root/openface/training-images/misha/1.jpg`? Also I assume 1.JPG is in the current working directory?

Comment: That error message comes from before 1.8, are you sure everything is running 1.10? Post `docker --version` and `docker info`

Comment: @BMitch Oh, my bad. I run `docker --version` and it gives me `Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2`. Also turns out I'm on 14.04, not 16.04. Sorry!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Version 1.6.2 doesn't allow copying from host to container, you need to upgrade to at least 1.8 for that support.