# docker cp requires 2 arguments

Tags: docker

if I use:

```
docker cp local_dir/*.py image_name:remote_dir



docker cp local_dir/. image_name:remote_dir
```

the former will give the error"docker cp requires exactly 2 arguments"

but the latter works.

Aren't both of the commands got 2 arguments?

Thanks!

Comment: The first one will have one argument for each Python file in `local_dir`.  Try putting `echo` at the front of both lines to see something closer to the actual expanded command lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy multiple local files to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153857/copy-multiple-local-files-to-docker-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first one is the wildcard format,
if you want to copy multi-files one time, try this:

```
ls local_dir/*.py |xargs -n 1 --verbose -I {} docker cp {} image_name:remote_dir
```