# docker cp the content of a folder

Tags: docker, nexus

I try to copy the content of a folder (on my server) to my container:

```
docker cp sonatype-work-backup/* nexus:/sonatype-work/
```

So I want the content of sonatype-work in my /sonatype-work/ of nexus. But it doesn't work with the `*` and without the star it's copying the directory sonatype-work-backup inside my sonatype-work directory. I can't perform `mv` after that.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container which lists various solutions

Answer (score 1):

you could just mount that directory in your container at run

```
 docker run -v /sonatype-work-backup:/mnt --name nexus nexus-image
```

then

```
docker exec -it nexus bash
```

and just cp from /mnt to your desired folder