# What are the reasons Docker cp works differently to Unix cp?

Tags: bash, unix, docker, cp

Suppose I have the following directory structure

```
parent-dir
+ child-dir
  + grandchild-file-a
  + grandchild-file-b
uncle-dir
  .
  ..
```

Now on unix - if I run the command

```
parent-dir> cp child-dir ../uncle-dir
```

Then I expect to get

```
uncle-dir
+ child-dir
  + grandchild-file-a
  + grandchild-file-b
```

But if I repeat this with `docker cp` then I get

```
uncle-dir
+ grandchild-file-a
+ grandchild-file-b
```

Which might be reasonable on unix if I had done:

```
parent-dir> cp child-dir/* ../uncle-dir
```

My question is: **What are the reasons Docker cp works differently to Unix cp?**

Comment: suppose it could be because of this behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455454/docker-cp-the-content-of-a-folder/37457401#37457401

Comment: @Zeromus That's not "a behavior" and it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You appear to have an alias like `cp=cp -r` set. By default, `cp` by itself won't copy a directory.

Comment: the question in the link is about copying all content of a folder in another but docker cp doesnt accept * wildcard. that's a behavior and if what @hawkeye described is true then that resolve the problem

Comment: @Zeromus But that question did link, eventually, to the docker docs which did explain the problem.

Comment: @Zeromus No, it gives a workaround for avoiding the `*` (that docker apparently doesn't like) it doesn't explain *why* `docker cp` is doing what it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker docs on [`cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) explain this:

> - SRC_PATH specifies a directory
>
>   - DEST_PATH does not exist
>
>     - DEST_PATH is created as a directory and the contents of the source directory are copied into this directory
>   - DEST_PATH exists and is a file
>
>     - Error condition: cannot copy a directory to a file
>   - DEST_PATH exists and is a directory
>
>     - SRC_PATH does not end with /.
>
>       - the source directory is copied into this directory
>     - SRC_PATH does end with /.
>
>       - the content of the source directory is copied into this directory

So either `DEST_PATH` does not exist or it does and your `docker cp` command is actually `docker cp child-dir/ uncle-dir` (with the trailing slash).

Comment: NOTE: 

1. As of 2023/07/21 the behavior and documentation has been updated 
2. `/.` slash followed by dot is important

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#description