# How to copy files from local machine to docker container on windows

Tags: file, docker, copy, containers, local

I have to import data files from a user local file C:/users/saad/bdd to a docker container (cassandra), I didn't find how to proceed using docker commands.
I'm working on windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from host to docker container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

Answer (score 115):

Use `docker cp`.

```
docker cp c:\path\to\local\file container_name:/path/to/target/dir/
```

If you don't know what's the name of the container, you can find it using:

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}}"
```

Comment: Thank you Alvaro for your quick answer, but when I try this code: docker cp C:\Users\Saad\bdd-restaurants cassandra:/var/lib/docker/containers, I get this error message: copying between containers is not supported

Comment: Also, how can I know the exact path of the container ?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers, there are already quite a few good answers in the linked question.

Comment: Ok, yes but everytime I try copying the files, it shows the same message "copying containers is not supported" do you know what does it mean please ?

Comment: @R0MANARMY understood. sorry about that.

Comment: @Manou I don't think your container has a /var/lib/docker/containers path. Your parent host (where you installed docker) surely does, but not the containers itself. I guess that's why it's giving you that error message.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you are using Docker for windows on Windows 7, and your container is a windows machine, then you will need to first stop the container in order to copy the file. Copying of files is not supported for running windows containers if they are Hyper V containers. The same command will however work fine if ran on Windows Server docker host. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31606

Answer (score 14):

When using docker toolbox, there seems to be another issue related to absolute paths.

I am communicating with the containers using the "Docker Quickstart Teminal" which essentially is a MINGW64 environment.

If I try to copy a file with an absolute path to a container, I receive the error message.

```
$ docker cp /d/Temp/my-super-file.txt container-name:/tmp/
copying between containers is not supported
```

If I use a relative path, it simply works.

```
$ cd /d/
$ docker cp Temp/my-super-file.txt container-name:/tmp/
```

P.S.: I am posting this as an answer because of missing reputation for a comment.

Answer (score 10):

Simple way:

From **DockerContainer To LocalMachine**

```
$docker cp containerId:/sourceFilePath/someFile.txt C:/localMachineDestinationFolder
```

From **LocalMachine To DockerContainer**

```
$docker cp C:/localMachineSourceFolder/someFile.txt containerId:/containerDestinationFolder
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not as straight-forward when using docker toolbox. Because docker toolbox has only access to `C:\Users\` folder and there is a Oracle Virtual Box Manager in between, when you do get to copy the folder it is not directly copied to the container but instead to a mounted volume handle by Oracle VM machine. Like so:

```
/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/19b65e5d9f607607441818d3923e5133c9a96cc91206be1239059400fa317611/_data
```

How I got around this is just editing my **DockerFile**:

```
FROM cassandra:latest

ADD cassandra.yml /etc/cassandra/
ADD import.csv /var/lib/cassandra/
EXPOSE 9042
```

And building it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using docker-toolbox on windows, use the following syntax

docker cp /C/Users/Saad/bdd-restaurants cassandra:/var/lib/docker/containers

Comment: Your answer seems identical to [Alvaro Carvajal's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40313917/3982001). Can you please [edit] it and explain why it is different? Otherwise, if it isn't different, please consider that additional answers should add something to what has already been said, otherwise they aren't useful. Thank you!

Comment: This helped me realize that when using WSL2 and DevContainers with VS Code, in WSL your drives show up as /mnt/<drive letter>.

Answer (score 3):

Use this command will help to copy files from host machine to docker container.

```
docker cp c:\abc.doc <containerid> :C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc.doc
```

Comment: It seems there should not be a space between <containerid> and the :C:\inetpub\...

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), Docker, and DevContainers from VSCode (Visual Studio Code), I was able to make this work by using the WSL command line.

```
docker cp "/mnt/<drive letter>/source/My First Copy Command"  <container id>:/workspace/destination/path
```

I also [wrote it up in more detail](https://www.aaronjgrossman.com/2022/04/21/copy-files-from-windows-to-devcontainers/).

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to copy file from windows to an EC2 instance use the following in cmd (Putty enabled):

```
pscp -i "D:\path_to_ppk_key" c:\file_name ubuntu@**.***.**.*:/home/ubuntu/file
```

Then you can copy to docker in EC2 using

```
docker cp /home/ubuntu/file_name Docker_name:/home/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use volume to mount the file to container on the run:

docker run -v /users/saad/bdd:/myfiles/tmp/