# Docker - Backup/export of data container volume used by another container

Tags: docker

I have run two Docker images:

`docker run --name=data mydata
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=master --volumes-from=data -d mymaster`

I need to have backups of the data container, just for security, and perhaps for a possible migration in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the data with the `cp` command (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/ and the example is from this answer [Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container))

```
docker cp foo.txt mycontainer:/foo.txt
docker cp mycontainer:/foo.txt foo.txt
```

You can get the name of your container with `docker ps`.

If you want to automate the whole thing, that's a chapter for itself.