# How can i upload data to docker (container)?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, boot2docker

I want to upload a .txt file to a container so later I can copy that file to paste it in a different container but I am new using docker and the manual is too complicated to understand.
Can someone help me? I am using a windows 10 computer.

Thanks!
Sarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using

`docker cp`

see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

you can also use netcat, see for example

https://github.com/chilcano/docker-netcat

if your container uses a volume, this is another way to do

https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you need keep the docker running.
then in a different terminal use `docker cp` command to copy the files/folders.