# how to deploy war file in tomcat 7 of docker container

Tags: java, docker, tomcat7

I don't know how to deploying the war file into tomcat 7 with the help of docker container.

It is easy in windows OS because we manually paste our project's war file into `webapps` folder of tomcat, but in case of docker container it is little bit difficult.

I don't know how to change port of tomcat and add role manager in `tomcat-users.xml` file in docker because of directory structure of docker container. and how to start tomcat using newly change port number in docker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the volume parameter (`-v`) with `docker run` to have the `webapps` directory and `tomcat-users.xml` file stay on the host filesystem, not on the container one.

**For instance, on a Linux host:**

- create a file named `/tmp/tomcat-users.xml` with the correct content for your needs;
- Then, create an empty directory named `/tmp/webapps`.

Now, run your container this way:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 -v /tmp/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml:ro -v /tmp/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps:rw tomcat:7
```

Then, since the container is started in foreground, connect to another shell (another window) and copy your war file into /tmp/webapps.
It will be automatically deployed.

**For instance, on a Windows host:**

- create a file named `c:\tmp\tomcat-users.xml` with the correct content for your needs;
- Then, create an empty directory named `c:\tmp\webapps`.

Now, run your container this way:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 -v //c/tmp/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml:ro -v //c/tmp/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps:rw tomcat:7
```

Then copy your war file into `c:\tmp\webapps`. It will be automatically deployed.

Comment: I've added an example in my answer.

Comment: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/D/tmp/tomcat-users.xml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a22ecafd3331690eacc04e8a5f54e7839bae9b0cc9cc71f020d4add2ff/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a22ecafd3331690eacc04e6df73b8a5f54e7839bae9b0cc9cc71f020d4add2ff/merged/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""
: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if specified host path exists and is expected type.

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer for docker on Windows hosts.

Comment: i follow step given by you but in browser tomcat cannot start.it is started when i run above command using port 8830. it also show deployment message in command prompt

Comment: in command prompt it show Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/newihexa.war has finished in 48,708 ms this message means it deploy successfully but problem occure in browser with url:- localhost:8830 it doest not show tomcat homepage

Comment: If you want the tomcat administration interface, you need to add the war file or directory in the directory c:\tmp\deploy. The tomcat administration interface is a war application like any other.

Comment: [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory this error message occurs. thanks in advanced @alexandre

Comment: This may be explained because you use a DNS name to connect to the database and the container does not know the associated IP address. Use IP address to check if this is the problem.

Comment: thank you very much finally it completed my task again thank you @alexandre

Answer (score 0):

As for March 2021, using a single command line solution on a Windows Docker, try this:

**docker run --name YourApp -v "c/WarFiles/YourApp.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/YourApp.war" -it -p 9090:8080 tomcat:7**

Then open your app at http://localhost:9090/YourApp

Note "double quote" in volume and **c** drive with "Linux" slash / in order to make it work.