# default postgresql.conf file from docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

how can i get to my host the postgresql.conf from a container? or where can i see the default one? one coworker gave me his config file to compare it to my own to see some changes i would need to make.

the file path on the container is:

```
postgres=# show config_file;
               config_file                
------------------------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

but i dont know how to get the file from the container to my host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using Docker cp:

`docker cp <container>:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`

Take a look at the following links:

[StackOverFlow Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)
[Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

Comment: i should have searched better, this is duplicated, thanks