# docker view directory within container

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-copy

I'm trying to copy some files from my docker container to my localhost, I read the documentation that the way to do this is

```
docker cp 'container':path/to/file dest/path
```

But this requires I know the path and directory within the container that I want to get to, how can I view the container's directory? I tried docker diff and docker inspect but these don't show me the container's file directory

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You'll first need to know the name of the instance running?

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID  IMAGE        COMMAND  CREATED  STATUS  PORTS  NAMES
36029...      image/image  ...      1 sec..  Up..    ...    some-container
```

Now, get inside the container and look for what you need. Assuming the container name is, **some-image.**

```
$ docker exec -it some-container /bin/bash

root@1f3420c939:/var/www/html#
```

If you already know the folder:

```
docker exec -it some-container ls /path/to/file
```

---

EDIT:

as noted by @Konrad Botor it's possible to use also the container id instead of the container name and more importantly not all images have `bash` installed (alpine is the most popular image not using it).

Here's an example with alpine:

```sh
docker run -d \
    --rm \
    --name my_alpine_container \
    alpine \
    sleep 3600

CONTAINER_ID=$( docker ps -q my_alpine_container )

# to "enter" the container:
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID sh
```

Comment: what do you mean by $instance_name are you refferring to the image name, containerID or what's listed under NAMES when using docker ps?

Comment: ok, is the instance running? If yes and you need to copy the file in the instance you use the last column. EDIT: what's listed under NAMES.

Comment: Container ID should work as well its name. Also not every image has Bash installed. For example, most of the Alpine based images do not.

Comment: If you have alpine image which does not have bash, you can use the second command mentioned above - `docker exec -it container_name ls` . Means that whatever you intend to run inside bash run it with docker container commands(as bash is not available inside the container).

Comment: alpine is using /bin/ash.  So just enter "docker exec -it <id> ash" will do.

Answer (score -7):

Try this out.

[Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

"docker ps" to find the container's directory.

Comment: `docker ps` will show you running containers, not the directory structure inside any given container.

Comment: docker ps is for another thing.