# Add files from local file system to running Docker container

Tags: docker, containers

Is it possible to add files from local file system to a running docker container? Or I need to stop the container and add the files using cp command and run the container again?

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate question. See link by @user3217526 above

Answer (score 1):

Try *docker cp*.

To **put** files **on** a container:

```
docker cp file.pdf container:/file.pdf
```

To **get** files **from** a docker container:

```
docker cp container:/file.pdf file.pdf
```