# SQL Server docker container how to load a file from Hard drive

Tags: sql-server, docker, path, containers

I use SQL Server docker container for the first time. I run and connect docker without a problem.

When I try to load XML file to variable using this script:

```
DECLARE @xmldata XML

SELECT @xmldata=BulkColumn
FROM 
OPENROWSET (BULK 'D:\DaneXML\NBP\a051z140314.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) as T1

SELECT @xmldata as Dokument
```

Normally parameter was a path to file on hard drive (just for learning)

Now certainly path to my hard drive (`D:\DaneXML\NBP\a051z140314.xml`) is not recognised, because I am 'inside' the container.

What should I do to load this file then?

Probably I have to add the file to the container, how should I do it?

And what would be a `PATH` to use in `OPENROWSET()`?

And please, remember that this is my first time with docker containers :)

Comment: With your container running, you can get in there and explore it using [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/). So you would run the container, then run something like `docker exec -it <container_name|container_id> powershell`.

Comment: it is not anwser to my question :)

Answer (score 2):

As this answer explain: [How to copy files from host to Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/how-to-copy-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

You could use a command like:

docker cp "[YOURFILEPATH]" [CoontainerName]:/var/opt/mssql/data/[FileNameOnDestiny]

Ex:
docker cp "D:\docs\Ohglab\Tyseg\Ejecución\backup producción\AlcofingerDB.bak"sqlserver1:/var/opt/mssql/data/AlcofingerDB.bak

Then you could use that file:

[image]