# Move docker bind-mount to volume

Tags: docker, volumes

Actually, I run my containers like this, for example :

```
docker run -v /nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
              ^
```

After reading the documentation, I discover volumes that are completely managed by docker. For some reasons, I want to change the way to run my containers, to do something like this :

```
docker run -v nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
              ^
```

I want to transfer my existing bind-mount to volumes.

But I don't want to lose the data into `/nexus-data` folder, is there a possibility to transfer this folder, to the new volume, whitout restart everything ? Because I've also Jenkins and Sonar containers for example, I just want to change the way to have persistent data. The is a proper way to do this ?

Comment: There may well be a first-class way of doing this, but a hacky solution would just be to mount both into a container, and then copying from one to the other from inside the container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try out following steps so that you will not loose your current `nexus-data`.

```
#>docker run -v nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
#>docker cp /nexus-data/. <container-name-or-id>:/nexus-data/
#>docker stop <container-name-or-id>
#>docker start <container-name-or-id>
```

`docker cp` will copy data from your host-machine's `/nexus-data` folder to container's FS `/nexus-data` folder which is your mounted volume.

Let me know if you face any issue while performing following steps.

Comment: What about the ports (-p flag), because they are already taken, I just put other and after it will be possible to come back with wanted ports ?

Comment: For example, my nexus container take the 8081, and I prefer to not change it.

Comment: Stop the first NEXUS container( which is actually using 8081) , since this container is already storing data in host's directory (/nexus)- you have all the required information outside of that container. Now start/create the new NEXUS container with mounted volume (nexus-data) and assigned the required port 8081, since at this point of time your 8081 port is free (old nexus-container is stopped)

Comment: Indeed, storage of the data has little to do with the port your nexus container is listening to. You can start and stop containers without losing data

Comment: For me, `docker copy /nexus-data/* <container-name-or-id>:/nexus-data` doesn't work, `docker cp /nexus-data/. <container-name-or-id>:/nexus-data` works. [Copying files from host to Docker container - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container).

Comment: @JasonLaw -- Edited the post to correct this. (First, alas incomplete, edit by [@besendorf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7580219/besendorf))

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do this, that I just used successfully with a [Heimdall](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/heimdall) container. It's outlined in the [documentation for the sonatype/nexus3 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/#persistent-data):

1. Stop the running container (e.g. named `nexus3`)
2. Create a docker volume called `nexus-data`, creating it with the following command: `docker volume create nexus-data`)
3. By default, Docker will store the volume's content at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/nexus-data/_data/`
4. Simply copy the directory where you previously had been using a bind mount to the aforementioned volume directory (you'll need super user privileges to do this, or for the user to be part of the `docker` group): `cp -R /path/to/nexus-data/* /var/lib/docker/volumes/nexus-data/_data/`
5. Restart the `nexus3` container with `$ docker run -v nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3 --name=nexus3`
6. Your container will be back up and running, with the files persisted in the directory `/path/to/nexus-data/` now mirrored in the docker volume. Check if functionality is the same, of course, and if so, you can delete the `/path/to/nexus-data/` directory

Q.E.D.