# Copying file from host to Docker container's working directory

Tags: docker

I am trying to copy files from a host that runs Debian/GNU Linux v9 to a docker container's **working directory**.  The container is [balenalib/beaglebone-black](https://hub.docker.com/r/balenalib/beaglebone-black) with some additions.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container), I understand the syntax to copy via `docker cp`.  I have tried this: `docker cp hostfile container_id:~/destinationfile`.  However, that obviously doesn't work because home directory may not be root directory.

How do I specify to copy the file into the docker container's working directory?

Comment: The documentation indeed clearly points at the fact that containers path are relative to `/` not to the workdir. That said, I would guess that `docker inspect` would help you getting the workdir of the said container, to pass that to the `cp`. Something like `docker cp hostFile containerId:$(docker inspect containerId [find the correct filter/option here])/hostFile` should be able to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: As @b.enoit.be said, if you want to copy a file to your container, you can do this like: docker cp yourfile ContainerID:/home. That "/home" can be another docker folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***TL;DR;***

```
docker cp hostFile containerId:$(docker inspect --format='{{.Config.WoringkDir}}' containerId)/hostFile
```

---

Here is what I found and how I found it:

As my comment stated it, I was pretty sure that [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) would have that kind of information.

From my experience, I know `docker inspect` gives out some JSON data and that there is a way to format that output.

So I launched a `httpd` container (because I know it has a working dir set), and just ran a unfiltered `docker inspect` on it.

1. Getting the container in a detached state

   ```
   $ docker run -d httpd
   Unable to find image 'httpd:latest' locally
   latest: Pulling from library/httpd
   f7e2b70d04ae: Pull complete
   84006542c688: Pull complete
   dae6fe3c5e81: Pull complete
   33fc493aff90: Pull complete
   9a4113020573: Pull complete
   Digest: sha256:20ead958907f15b638177071afea60faa61d2b6747c216027b8679b5fa58794b
   Status: Downloaded newer image for httpd:latest
   5d85e4926b578e15abdb92650a56f6507d01f04a31de33f179583eccf0a3a6c3
   ```
2. Finding its friendly name

   ```
   $ docker ps -a
   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS         NAMES
   5d8e4926b57        httpd               "httpd-foreground"   12 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds       80/tcp         friendly_murdock
   ```
3. A quick grep to insure what we are looking for is there*

   ```
   $ docker inspect friendly_murdock | grep Work
                   "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c3b938dfd53dd42370953ac6bfc04bce444588ca449a43b922e0ba41b189102b/work"
               "WorkingDir": "/usr/local/apache2",
   ```
4. Getting the full information to see where the info is in the JSON hierarchy; that points at the fact that `WorkingDir` is under `Config` (scroll around 3/4 of the JSON to discover it by yourself)*

   ```
   $ docker inspect friendly_murdock
   [
      {
         "Id": "5d85e4926b578e15abdb92650a56f6507d01f04a31de33f179583eccf0a3a6c3",
         "Created": "2019-03-13T20:37:31.489661896Z",
         "Path": "httpd-foreground",
         "Args": [],
         "State": {
               "Status": "running",
               "Running": true,
               "Paused": false,
               "Restarting": false,
               "OOMKilled": false,
               "Dead": false,
               "Pid": 2051,
               "ExitCode": 0,
               "Error": "",
               "StartedAt": "2019-03-13T20:37:31.961474223Z",
               "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
         },
         "Image": "sha256:2d1e5208483c26822b518c4ffa34ce1cd960f3e90e9be6ffe4c52cc6f5d5492c",
         "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/5d85e4926b578e15abdb92650a56f6507d01f04a31de33f179583eccf0a3a6c3/resolv.conf",
         "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/5d85e4926b578e15abdb92650a56f6507d01f04a31de33f179583eccf0a3a6c3/hostname",
         "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/5d85e4926b578e15abdb92650a56f6507d01f04a31de33f179583eccf0a3a6c3/hosts",
         "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/5d85e4926b578e15abdb92650a56f6507d01f04a31de33f179583eccf0a3a6c3/5d85e4926b578e15abdb92650a56f6507d01f04a31de33f179583eccf0a3a6c3-json.log",
         "Name": "/friendly_murdock",
         "RestartCount": 0,
         "Driver": "overlay2",
         "Platform": "linux",
         "MountLabel": "",
         "ProcessLabel": "",
         "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
         "ExecIDs": null,
         "HostConfig": {
               "Binds": null,
               "ContainerIDFile": "",
               "LogConfig": {
                  "Type": "json-file",
                  "Config": {}
               },
               "NetworkMode": "default",
               "PortBindings": {},
               "RestartPolicy": {
                  "Name": "no",
                  "MaximumRetryCount": 0
               },
               "AutoRemove": false,
               "VolumeDriver": "",
               "VolumesFrom": null,
               "CapAdd": null,
               "CapDrop": null,
               "Dns": [],
               "DnsOptions": [],
               "DnsSearch": [],
               "ExtraHosts": null,
               "GroupAdd": null,
               "IpcMode": "shareable",
               "Cgroup": "",
               "Links": null,
               "OomScoreAdj": 0,
               "PidMode": "",
               "Privileged": false,
               "PublishAllPorts": false,
               "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
               "SecurityOpt": null,
               "UTSMode": "",
               "UsernsMode": "",
               "ShmSize": 67108864,
               "Runtime": "runc",
               "ConsoleSize": [
                  0,
                  0
               ],
               "Isolation": "",
               "CpuShares": 0,
               "Memory": 0,
               "NanoCpus": 0,
               "CgroupParent": "",
               "BlkioWeight": 0,
               "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
               "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
               "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
               "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
               "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
               "CpuPeriod": 0,
               "CpuQuota": 0,
               "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
               "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
               "CpusetCpus": "",
               "CpusetMems": "",
               "Devices": [],
               "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
               "DiskQuota": 0,
               "KernelMemory": 0,
               "MemoryReservation": 0,
               "MemorySwap": 0,
               "MemorySwappiness": null,
               "OomKillDisable": false,
               "PidsLimit": 0,
               "Ulimits": null,
               "CpuCount": 0,
               "CpuPercent": 0,
               "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
               "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
               "MaskedPaths": [
                  "/proc/asound",
                  "/proc/acpi",
                  "/proc/kcore",
                  "/proc/keys",
                  "/proc/latency_stats",
                  "/proc/timer_list",
                  "/proc/timer_stats",
                  "/proc/sched_debug",
                  "/proc/scsi",
                  "/sys/firmware"
               ],
               "ReadonlyPaths": [
                  "/proc/bus",
                  "/proc/fs",
                  "/proc/irq",
                  "/proc/sys",
                  "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
               ]
         },
         "GraphDriver": {
               "Data": {
                  "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c3b938dfd53dd42370953ac6bfc04bce444588ca449a43b922e0ba41b189102b-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bffe6a5f69cd186be0fbe6ac4d1a18c9f33a59eb1d2dfc4704fc0b5d9202d565/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/13828a5afe316d7a37ded8f3c42e05ceb715ac494773ebe285e0a458edc6f5eb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9e4ef1c4b0bdb2bd958bceefe3ca911ec70613445dc58e600237110ecd938226/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/31b84ae126e4483a5dea9476d076a6a3dd21833f4e27777512a5302157519a3c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/982c67754fe156ee05e0675889cd648f1c4f8c4a115cf0ab0c83bdb457228845/diff",
                  "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c3b938dfd53dd42370953ac6bfc04bce444588ca449a43b922e0ba41b189102b/merged",
                  "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c3b938dfd53dd42370953ac6bfc04bce444588ca449a43b922e0ba41b189102b/diff",
                  "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c3b938dfd53dd42370953ac6bfc04bce444588ca449a43b922e0ba41b189102b/work"
               },
               "Name": "overlay2"
         },
         "Mounts": [],
         "Config": {
               "Hostname": "5d85e4926b57",
               "Domainname": "",
               "User": "",
               "AttachStdin": false,
               "AttachStdout": false,
               "AttachStderr": false,
               "ExposedPorts": {
                  "80/tcp": {}
               },
               "Tty": false,
               "OpenStdin": false,
               "StdinOnce": false,
               "Env": [
                  "PATH=/usr/local/apache2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                  "HTTPD_PREFIX=/usr/local/apache2",
                  "HTTPD_VERSION=2.4.38",
                  "HTTPD_SHA256=7dc65857a994c98370dc4334b260101a7a04be60e6e74a5c57a6dee1bc8f394a",
                  "HTTPD_PATCHES=",
                  "APACHE_DIST_URLS=https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?action=download&filename= \thttps://www-us.apache.org/dist/ \thttps://www.apache.org/dist/ \thttps://archive.apache.org/dist/"
               ],
               "Cmd": [
                  "httpd-foreground"
               ],
               "ArgsEscaped": true,
               "Image": "httpd",
               "Volumes": null,
               "WorkingDir": "/usr/local/apache2",
               "Entrypoint": null,
               "OnBuild": null,
               "Labels": {}
         },
         "NetworkSettings": {
               "Bridge": "",
               "SandboxID": "971f52a7ce81d0c5ceb1e501101ea852d5a9898c57c5f6bbe4b96c9efcc016db",
               "HairpinMode": false,
               "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
               "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
               "Ports": {
                  "80/tcp": null
               },
               "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/971f52a7ce81",
               "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
               "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
               "EndpointID": "07e63ff9d1c53ad639a9d2bc065cd901afb00024395d22527a2d0297a98691fb",
               "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
               "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
               "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
               "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
               "IPPrefixLen": 16,
               "IPv6Gateway": "",
               "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
               "Networks": {
                  "bridge": {
                     "IPAMConfig": null,
                     "Links": null,
                     "Aliases": null,
                     "NetworkID": "8c894781eecadaf63f14ad1da23c26abb42ef3316f7d6ebd1c89b3adac96d99c",
                     "EndpointID": "07e63ff9d1c53ad639a9d2bc065cd901afb00024395d22527a2d0297a98691fb",
                     "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                     "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                     "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                     "IPv6Gateway": "",
                     "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                     "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                     "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                     "DriverOpts": null
                  }
               }
         }
      }
   ]
   ```
5. Finding the right command with the help of the [documentation examples](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#examples)

   ```
   $ docker inspect --format='{{.Config.WorkingDir}}' friendly_murdock
   /usr/local/apache2
   ```
6. Combine it whit what we know already*

   ```
   docker cp hostFile containerId:$(docker inspect --format='{{.Config.WoringkDir}}' containerId)/hostFile
   ```

Comment: Wow that is perfect, thank you @b.enoit.be!  This was useful and I am going to implement this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a volume to copy a file from host to container as follows:

```
docker run -it --volume $PWD/directory:/tmp/dir balenalib/beaglebone-black
```

Note that you cannot use relative paths to mount volumes on cli form. To do that use docker-compose instead:

```
version: "3"
services:
  beaglebone: 
    image: balenalib/beaglebone-black 
    volumes: "../dir:/tmp/dir"
...
```

Then run docker-compose:

```
docker-compose up
```

Check the docs on volume types.

> https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: To add to this, you can use `docker run -v` to inject single files or whole directories to containers at startup time, which is generally easier to run and more reliable than trying to copy the file as a separate action.