# How to copy a file from host to Kubernetes container?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to copy a file from my Ubuntu machine to kube-controller-manager-ubuntu container. Currently I do that [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container), but I think it has more straight solution in Kubernetes.

Does anyone know how to copy a file to a Kubernetes container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is similar to docker copy.

```
kubectl cp /tmp/foo_dir <some-pod>:/tmp/bar_dir
```

Please refer here for examples and documentation

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using namespace then you wanna go like this -

```
kubectl cp ./file.csv <CONTAINER_ID>:/path/to/copy -n <namespace>
```

e.g.

```
kubectl ./file.csv b81dd0b1745c:/usr/cloud_ms/ -n cloud
```