# How to make file permanent with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have an API running in a Kubernetes container that writes data to a file. The file path is set to "/home/dataset.arff" inside the container the file gets created successfully but it get deleted when the container is deleted. I need to make this file permanat because I have  another API using .
Is there a way to achieve this ?
(Im using docker desktop to enable k8s)

Comment: Trying to share data in files can be troublesome, especially in a cluster environment like Kubernetes.  Can you provide the data via some other path, like an HTTP API?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Persistent Volumes (PVs) and Persistent Volume Claims (PVCs)
Maybe search on web how to setup this.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), which seems to be what you are looking for.

If you cannot implement something like this, kubectl enables copying from a pod to host: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55673655/21164658
This could be somewhat automated using shell scripts.

Comment: I read about PV but what I understand is that the file gonna be permanat in my host machine directory  wich is windows in my case am I correct ? if yes does the other API will still be able to use that file  ?

Comment: You can konfigure PVs in a way that multiple pods can access it, yes. What you need to do precisely depends on your specific usecase.