# Add a file in a docker image

Tags: docker

I've created a docker image of a project (very large project that takes time to compile) and I forgot to add a file in it.

I does not have to do with the build, it's just a test file.

Is it possible to add this file into my image without rebuilding everything ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

Comment: If you add at the end of the Dockerfile it won't recompile everything

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes its possible, do the steps:

1. Mount the image and make a container
2. Do the command:

   docker cp textFile.txt docker_container_name:/textFile.txt
3. Commit the container to build a new image with new tag version or another name;

Comment: ```
$ Mount the image and make a container
bash: command not found: Mount
```

Answer (score 46):

Here's a full example to pull an image, add a local file to it, retag the image and push it back:

```
export IMAGE_URL=example.com/your_image:your_tag
docker pull $IMAGE_URL
docker create --name temp_container $IMAGE_URL
docker cp /host/path/to/file temp_container:/container/path/to/file
docker commit temp_container $IMAGE_URL
docker push $IMAGE_URL
```

Comment: This is by far the most succinct answer so far.  Yes - it covers much of the same ground as the previous answers but doesn't assume I have expert mastery of the docker cli.  e.g. "Mount your container"

Comment: Note: This may change unrelated values in your images. In my case, it changed the entrypoint command and "AttachStdout"/"AttachStderr" values (as seen when comparing diff <(docker inspect old) <(docker inspect new). It's possible this happened to me because the image was created with a different version of Docker, though.

Comment: I like it... Simple... Easy to remember...

Answer (score 6):

Add the image using docker commit of a container as described above, or using Dockerfile.

1. Create a directory say ***temp*** and navigate into it
2. Move file ***file-to-be-added.extension*** to be added to the docker image into the newly created ***temp*** directory
3. Create a Dockerfile with below contents

Dockerfile

```
FROM your-registry/your-image:tag
COPY file-to-be-added.extension /destination/path/of/file-to-be-added.extension
```

Run below command to build the new image:

> docker build -t your-registry/your-image:new-tag .

If required, push the image

> docker push your-registry/your-image:new-tag

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/).

Example: `docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]`

There's [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) too, but it only works in running containers.

I hope this helps!

Brhaka

Answer (score 1):

The ADD command is used to copy files/directories into a Docker image. It can copy data in three ways:

```
1. List item Copy files from the local storage to a destination in the Docker image.

2. Copy a tarball from the local storage and extract it automatically inside a destination in the Docker image.

3. Copy files from a URL to a destination inside the Docker image.
```

[image]

source: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-docker-add-command

Comment: OP doesn't want to re-build the docker image. He just wants to add a file to an existing image. Your suggestion requires the docker image to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Just patch your docker image:

```
export TAG=/your/docker/tag
export FILE=/path/to/your/file/to/add

cd `dirname $FILE`
FILENAME=`basename $FILE` echo "FROM ${TAG}\nADD ${FILENAME} /some_dir/{FILENAME}" | docker build -t ${TAG} -
```