# Creating a NodeJS/VueJS Docker Image in a Disconnected Environment

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, vuejs2

I'm in a totally disconnected network developing a VueJS2 app.

I've been lucky to be allowed to bring everything I need on a CD to be scanned and blessed and eventually put in a spot where I can go get it and develop from there.Now I'm trying to Dockerize this VueJS2 app with NodeJS.  (Works great in connected environment)

Note: I brought `node:lts-alpine` in as a tar file and then turned that into an image

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json /app

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . /app

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8060
CMD ["node", "server.prod.js"]
```

This works great when connected, but complains as some of the node_modules still want to reach out to the internet.  I've taken care to ensure that what I need is already in the node_modules folder.

What do I need to do to tell Docker, npm, or whatever not to go and look on the internet?

The error I'm getting is on the `RUN npm install` for a network request to `yargs-parser`.

`yars` and `yargs-parser` are in the node_modules folder.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest building your image while connected to the public Internet, and then bringing that built image (and not its Dockerfile) into the restricted environment.  This is the one case where `docker save` your image makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the response!!  I ended up doing that and then made required changes on the restricted side (created temp container,  updated temp container, and commit back to image).  Worked like a champ!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670437/add-a-file-in-a-docker-image