# How to pass google cloud application credentials file to docker container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, tensorflow-serving

I would like to pass my Google Cloud Platform's service account JSON credentials file to a docker container so that the container can access a cloud storage bucket. So far I tried to pass the file as an environment parameter on the run command like this:

- Using the **--env** flag: `docker run -p 8501:8501 --env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/gcp_credentials.json" -t -i image_name`
- Using the **-e** flag and even exporting the same env variable in the command line: `docker run -p 8501:8501 -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/gcp_credentials.json" -t -i image_name`

But nothing worked, and I always get the following error when running the docker container:

> W
> external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/google_auth_provider.cc:184]
> All attempts to get a Google authentication bearer token failed,
> returning an empty token. Retrieving token from files failed with "Not
> found: Could not locate the credentials file.".

How to pass the google credentials file to a container running locally on my personal laptop?

Comment: If you are running on Compute Engine, use a volume mount. Then you can specify **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/volume/mount/path" as a normal environment variable inside your container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a file in a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670437/add-a-file-in-a-docker-image)

Comment: @JohnHanley It rather seems to be the situation, to connect from a local container to GCS in order to run TF2, despite the question doesn't literally state that.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - Hi Martin, I am not sure what you mean. The only Google service that supports running Docker is Compute Engine. That is why I said, "If you are running on Compute Engine".

Comment: @JohnHanley The question does not tell where the container runs, while the `docker` command seemingly had been issued in a local shell ...that's why I'd assume this scenario. Ir probably doesn't even matter where it runs, while the task is to add a config file into it.

Comment: Does my article help? https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, like Martin said, Im running the container in my personal laptop. Sorry for forgetting to mention it on my post, which I have just edited accordingly. Thank you

Comment: Docker volume mount work on your laptop as well.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "pass" an external path, but have to add the JSON **into** the container.

Answer (score 3):

I log into gcloud in my local environment then share that json file as a volume in the same location in the container.

Here is great post on how to do it with relevant extract below: [Use Google Cloud user credentials when testing containers locally](https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da)

Login locally

> To get your default user credentials on your local environment, you
> have to use the gcloud SDK. You have 2 commands to get authentication:
>
> gcloud auth login to get authenticated on all subsequent gcloud
> commands gcloud auth application-default login to create your ADC
> locally, in a “well-known” location.

Note location of credentials

> The Google auth library tries to get a valid credentials by performing
> checks in this order
>
> Look at the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` value.
> If exists, use it, else… Look at the metadata server (only on Google
> Cloud Platform). If it returns correct HTTP codes, use it, else… Look
> at “well-know” location if a user credential JSON file exists The
> “well-known” locations are
>
> On linux: `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` On
> Windows: `%appdata%/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`

Share volume with container

> Therefore, you have to run your local docker run command like this
>
> ADC=~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json \ docker run
> \  
> -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json 
> -v ${ADC}:/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json:ro \ <IMAGE_URL>

NB: this is only for local development, on Google Cloud Platform the credentials for the service are automatically inserted for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

- Volumes: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
- Secrets: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

**secrets** - work with docker swarm mode.

- create docker secrets
- use secret with a container using *--secret*

Advantage being, secrets are encrypted. Secrets are decrypted when mounted to containers.