# How to docker cp correctly?

Tags: docker

I am trying to copy a file from my host to my container. I have already checked out many threads but neither of those work out for me.

File name, I'm trying to copy: **ex.txt**

Container folder where it needs to be: **my_folder**

```
user:~$ docker exec -it my_container bash
a5b13d9a55fd:~S ls
my_folder
```

What I have tried so far:

```
user:~$ docker cp ex.txt my_container:/my_folder/
no such directory

user:~$ docker cp ex.txt my_container:/my_folder/ex.txt
Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/f7796d886aa3673be37b1d346190b7d6ba0ed64edf83bf62bff325f87eaec5eb/my_folder: no such file or directory
```

Please suggest where am I missing the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: since the Image seems to use a none ROOT Use**r
you may try this:

```
docker cp ex.txt my_container:$HOME/my_folder/ex.txt
```

you should make sure that `my_folder` is already in the container, to be sure run this command at first:

```
docker exec my_container_name mkdir -p $HOME/my_folder
```

Comment: `sudo docker exec my_container mkdir -p /my_folder` It seem like I cannot create such folder:
mkdir: cannot create directory '/my_folder': Permission denied

Answer (score 3):

Please go through [offical](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) documentation properly.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container) out.

In your case this should work.

```
docker cp ex.txt my_container:/my_folder/
```

**Update-1:**

In your case, I doubt `/my_folder` is not present inside the container, this is what the error says.

Also quoting the line mentioned in [official](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) documentation.

> docker cp does not create parent directories for DEST_PATH if they do
>   not exist.

So the `/my_folder` directory will not get created automatically.

Do this. `docker exec -it my_container mkdir /my_folder` and then run docker cp command.

**Update-2:**

If nothing is working then please try this, it worked for me.

```
$ cat /root/ex.txt
abc
$ docker run -itd alpine sh
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
921b31ab772b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ca1c944a4f8486a153024d9965aafbe24f5723c1d5c02f4964c045a16d19dc54
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
35ad53b81c30f675b28a53e6a266f039cf49e90705d41e499deb4f17ab900255
$
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
35ad53b81c30        alpine              "sh"                3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            mystifying_babbage
$
$ docker exec -it 35ad53b81c30 sh
/ # ls
bin    dev    etc    home   lib    media  mnt    opt    proc   root   run    sbin   srv    sys    tmp    usr    var
/ # mkdir /my_folder
$
$ docker cp /root/ex.txt mystifying_babbage:/my_folder/
$
$ docker exec -it 35ad53b81c30 sh
/ # ls /my_folder/
ex.txt
/ # cat /my_folder/ex.txt
abc
/ #
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have written my commands falsely in the post. I have corrected it. so your command is actually what I have already tried

Comment: You need to ensure that `/my_folder` actually exists inside the container before you can copy a file into that directory.

Comment: when I do `docker exec -it my_container` and then list all folders, my_folder shows up

Comment: I tried the same command I mentioned in my answer and it worked for me. Please provide more details.

Comment: Updated my answer please try the steps at your end which I mentioned in update-2 section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure also not having typos in the container name, otherwise the same error will show up too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows, and the problem is it seems `docker cp` does not support trailing `\`, for instance:

```
docker cp toto.txt my_container:C:\MyFolderThatExitsOnContainer
```

does not work, but:

```
docker cp toto.txt my_container:C:\MyFolderThatExitsOnContainer\
```

gives me the `no such directory` error.

I assume there may be the same issue on Linux with `/`.