# Get a file from a path when runs a container

Tags: c#, docker

I have a problem with a docker container. I have a solution in C#, this solution needs a .config file at start and this file is always in C:\DBConnection\DBConnection.config. Now I'm wondering if it's possible, when I start a cointainer with run command, to take this file from the host C:\DBConnection directory and bring it in container, so the solution can read it. Sorry if I'm not clear, feel free to ask for more information if you need. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You could mount that file inside the container in a path which you can specify and your program running inside the container can read the file.

Comment: Can you tell me how you are running the container. I mean is it using just `docker` or are you using `docker-compose`.

Comment: I'm running the container with docker (I'm newbie of docker still didn't approach to docker-compose world).

Comment: And this container is already built and you cannot or do not want to rebuild it again ?

Comment: You can use `docker cp` to copy files to your container.

Refer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container

Comment: I will give you more details. I created a solution (webAPI), then I created a private registry on my PC. After i made the solution, I publish the image on my private registry with the Visual Studio 2019 tool. So, I want others people able to download my image and start it in a cointainer with docker run. But this application needs for working to read this config file, and people will knows that they have to create a folder C:\DBConnection with a specific DBConnection.config file before they give the run command. But how i can make the container bring this file with him after the run command?

Comment: Okay let me see if I got it right. You built a `docker image`. Anyone who wants to run this `image` needs a `DBConnection.config` in their `C:\DBConnection` path in the host machine ( which is the machine they are running the `docker` from). Now you want this `config` file to be copied inside the `container` from  `C:\DBConnection` in the host machine while the `docker run` command is run ?

Comment: Exactly, you got it.

Comment: Why not put the `config` file inside the `image` which you are giving to the user ? Unless you want the file in the host machine and the container to be linked. Do you want it to be linked ? As in if you change the `config` in the host machine, the `config` file will change in the container.

Comment: I would have a configurable file from other users before starting the container.

Comment: Alright, then you can `mount ` the config file into the `container` as you run the command. So it's available from outside.