# How to restore oracle database in docker from RMAN backup outside container

Tags: oracle, docker, containers, rman

I was looking for a solution but unfortunately I couldn't find the right answer.
I have docker container with oracle database (**database-enterprise:12:2:0.1**) and I have rman backup (archivelogs, controlfile, spfile) on Windows.

How can I upload this backup into container and make recovery database or another good solution - run new database from this backup ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question and you haven't given us a lot of details, so I'll answer it in broad terms.

See this duplicate question for [copying files from host to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

Now that you have your backup files on the server, there are several steps involved in RMAN recovery. I'll list them briefly here, but [this guide covers them in more detail](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/11/oracle-rman-restore/).

1. Restore SPFILE (sets global system parameters including controlfile location)
2. Restore CONTROLFILE (sets system configuration - where the datafiles are, etc. On a working database, you can [backup the controlfile to trace](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_database_backup_controlfile_to_trace.htm) to view the config details)
3. Restore database (using a backupset - basically just copies of the datafiles)
4. Recover database (applies archived redo logs to bring the datafiles forward in time)
5. Reset the logs (if you don't have enough redo logs to complete the recovery)
6. Open the database

For an exhaustive level of detail, [Oracle has written an entire book of documentation about RMAN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmintro.htm).