# \copy table via psql from local to Docker container from within the container

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

Disclaimer: Not talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container).

How can I execute `\copy` command from `psql` when I'm inside the live docker container?

When I try `\copy table from '/home/Snow/Documents/table.csv' with delimiter as ',' csv header;` 
I get the error:

> No such file or directory

Is there a different path I should write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From outside the container you can import a file using `psql` with the following command:

```
$ cat table.csv | psql -h docker_container -d db -c \
"COPY table FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV"
```

- Replace `docker_container` with the IP or hostname of the container
- In case your postgres isn't configured to accept external connections, change it in the `postgres.conf` file: e.g. `listen_addresses = '*'` to listen to all external connections.

Comment: the file.csv is located outside the container, and I execute the command from within the container filesystem. Not from `/home/Snow/Documents/`

Comment: so you don't have the option of executing this command from outside the container?

Comment: no I can't because the postgres database is located inside the container, so I can't access it from outside

Comment: using psql you can. You just need to pass the hostname using the parameter `-h`, e.g. `psql -h localhost -U user -d db -c "..."`, `psql -h 192.168.1.42 -U user -d db -c "..."`

Comment: very interesting, so that `-h localhost` makes the difference. I thought that localhost would be the default host... If i remove that part I can't login with that user anymore

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure whether I should accept the answer or not, since my question is about copying the table from within the container. However, it did solve my issue

Comment: @Snow well, I'm not veeery familiar with docker, but I guess it would suffice to go to the directory (inside the container), execute `pwd` and copy the path into your `copy` command. In case the file is outside the container, it could be that the volume wasn't specified when you started the container. Thanks for the upvote anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to either copy the file to your docker container or mount the directory.

To copy the file, follow the procedure in the question to which you linked, something like:

`docker cp /home/Snow/Documents/table.csv your_container:/`

Then, from within your container, you could import access the file:

`\copy table from '/table.csv' with delimiter as ',' csv header;`

Alternatively, when you created the container, you could have added a volume with the -v option like:

`docker run -v /home/Snow/Documents:/data postgres`

and then your Documents directory would be at /data allowing you to import like this:

`\copy table from '/data/table.csv' with delimiter as ',' csv header;`