# How do I pass a file into a Docker container to be used with the container?

Tags: docker, containers, command-line-interface

I would like to pass a file from the host system to a container at runtime. I want to run a CLI tool within a container and use the file as an argument to the CLI tool. Is it possible to modify the following command: `docker run -it --rm --name <container-name>` to achieve what I want to do. The `docker cp` command doesn’t work for what I need since it doesn’t run from within the container and I need to pass the file name as an argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

Comment: `docker cp` command doesn’t quite do what I want since it is used from the host system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually use the `-v "$PWD:$PWD" -w "$PWD"` trick. Run container and volume mount the current host working directory into the container at the same path and set working directory to same path.

So for example if I want to transcode a wav file on the host to a mp3 file usig ffmpeg running in a container I would do:

```sh
docker run --rm -v "$PWD:$PWD" -w "$PWD" mwader/static-ffmpeg:4.2.2 -i file.wav file.mp3
```

You can also add `-u $UID:$GROUPS` if your unsure what default user the image runs as.

Comment: (Consider whether it's better to just run the tool directly on the host, outside of Docker: the command line glue to get a Docker container to work on local files is longer than the command itself, especially if you do need to also manually specify the user ID.)

Comment: Ah yes should! use docker if it's easier because packaging, try different versions etc. For a shell you could make it smooth with an alias `alias ffmpeg='docker run --rm -v "$PWD:$PWD" -w "$PWD" mwader/static-ffmpeg:4.2.2'`