# Is it possible? : docker running image with host files

Tags: docker

I have a little question about docker. Please understand me, I`m elementary level about docker. I'm using CentOS 7 Linux.

When I use docker (images), (espatially dropest(https://dropest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#installation) I understand, and download image successfully with code below :

`docker pull vpetukhov/dropest:latest`

and get start with code below :

`docker run -it vpetukhov/dropest`

and copy my files to runing with dropest
([Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)) with code below :

`docker cp ./myfile acb889c0c379:/home/user`

and running dropest(the program what I use), after running dropest, copy output files to my linux server.

`docker cp acb889c0c379:~/outputFilePath/outputFile.txt ./outputFile.txt`

In conclusion: docker run CONTAINER -> copy file to CONTAINER -> running program -> copy outputFile to server.
I just want use 'dropest' program! there is nothing else what I want in Container.

Is there any other option? like:

`[myID@server]$docker run [something option] dropest (dropest command with myFiles)`(myFiles are located on server)

then obtain outputFiles on server

Please help. Best regards.

Comment: One of Docker's main _design goals_ is to isolate the host and container filesystems from each other.  That makes it an awkward packaging mechanism for tools like this.  I'd install the program directly on your host instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just bind-mount your files into your container?
e.g. `docker run -v "/path/to/your/files:/files" -ti --rm vpetukhov/dropest:latest /files/`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Look at the life cycle about docker container!
I follow this picture to make solve the problem
@Niels Hofmans's answer is really useful for me.

If you are korean, please try visit
here :https://0902.tistory.com/4
and here :https://0902.tistory.com/6?category=675093

first,

`docker create -v [path where you want on your server]:[path where you want on your CONTAINER] --name [what you want] -it vpetukhov/dropest`

In my case:

`docker create -v /home/hanjg/imsi:/home/user/Data_host --name imsi_mount -it vpetukhov/dropest`

You don`t have to make imsi folder(directory) and Data_host folder(directory). docker make folder automatically.

`docker start imsi_mount`

`docker attach imsi_mount`

Finally, you are enter your CONTAINER and try
`cd Data_host`

It is same as '/home/hanjg/imsi' on your server! : '/home/hanjg/imsi' repository mount on docker CONTAINER! (in my case vpetukhov/dropest CONTAINER)

Thanks!