# How to copy docker container directories to Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm new to Google Cloud and Docker and I can't for the life of me figure out how to copy directories from the Docker container (pushed to the Container Registry) to the Google Compute Engine instance. I think I need to mount the volume but I don't really know how. In the docker container the main directory is /app which has my files. Basically I want to do this to see the docker container's files in Google Cloud.

I assumed that if i did: docker pull [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[TAG] inside the cloud shell that the files would show up somewhere in the cloud shell i.e. in var/lib/docker but when I cd to var/lib/docker and type in: ls I get

`ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied`

Just to add I've tried following the "Connecting to Cloud Storage buckets" tutorial https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets
But realised that this is for single files. Is it possible to copy over the whole root directory of the Docker image using gsutil? Do I need to use something else instead, like persistent disks?

Comment: `docker cp CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: Perfect answer of @JohnHanley!! You need to have docker installed on your Compute Engine. Use COS boot image on your compute engine, it's easier!

Comment: Thank you @John Hanley will try that. Also do you by any chance know where to store the keyfile to be used to authenticate Docker? It seems a bit strange to store it in the Docker container itself but I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere thank you. I am using a COS image right now.

Comment: What do you mean by `authenticate Docker`? Do you mean authenticate to Google Container Registry or something else? If you mean to provide a service account to the container, typically you would use Docker Volumes https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ For Compute Engine COS look at `--container-mount-host-path` https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create-with-container#--container-mount-host-path AND set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` when launching the instance using the `--container-env=` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have docker installed in order to run your images and of course be able to copy anything from inside the image to your host filesystem.

Use `docker cp CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH` to copy files.

Have a look at the official [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) on how to use this command.
Simillar topic was also [discussed here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31971697/12257250) and has a very good answer.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm just wondering how I'd copy over the whole Docker filesystem? Is that something that could even be done on a GCE? The reason why I want to do that is so that I can have the Docker directories be accessible from the cloud shell. Also when setting up authentication where would I store the Keyfile to be used in the Google Compute Engine? I think its a bit counter intuitive to store it in the Docker container itself.

Comment: You can copy almost everything but it depends on what you're running in a container. When I ran `docker cp container:/ .` I got an error but was able to copy most files with directory structure. Only those that are in use may not get copied or will be outdated/corrupted.