# "Building Image" task hangs in VS Code Dev Container when using a large directory

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm using Visual Studio Code on a Windows machine. I'm trying to setup a Python Dev Container using a directory that contains a large set of CSV files (about 200GB). When I click to launch the remote container in Visual Studio the application hangs saying `(Starting Dev Container (show log): Building image.`

I've been looking through the docs and having read the [Advanced Container Configuation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_use-a-named-volume-for-your-entire-source-tree) I've tried modifying the `devcontainer.json` file by adding `workspaceMount` and `workspaceFolder` entries:

```
"workspaceMount" : "source=//c/path/to/folder,target=/workspace,type=bind,consistency=delegated"
"workspaceFolder" : "/workspace"
```

But to no avail. Is there a solution to launching Dev Containers on Windows using folders which contain large files?

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly different problem, but the solution might help you or someone else. I was trying to run docker-compose inside a docker-in-docker image (provided by vscode). In my case, my container was able to start, but nothing inside the container was able to run.

To solve my issue, I updated vscode and and now there is a new option `Remote-Containers: Clone Repository in Container Volume...`. If your code is a git repo, you can do this:

**Step #1:**
[image]

**Step #2:**
[image]

**Step #3 and onwards:**
Follow the given steps provided by vscode and you should have your repository in the container as a volume. It reduced my building times from about 30mins to 3mins (*within* the running container) because I brought stuff into the container *after* it was up and running.

Assuming the 200GB is ignored by your `.gitignore`, what you could try to do is once the container has started, you can [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31971697/3645855) the 200GB worth of excel files into the container. I thought this would help because I did a similar thing by bringing in all my node_modules *after* running the container.

Comment: For anyone using node out there, `npm run dev` runs faster using this method.