# Copy files to a Docker image using entrypoint instead of dockerfile for GitHub actions

Tags: docker, dockerfile, building-github-actions

I created a `Dockerfile` for my website development ([Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) in this case, but I do not think that matters much).

In case this information is helpful, I code locally using Visual Studio Code and the [Remote Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension. This extension allows me to manage my code locally while keeping it in sync with the container.

To publish my website, I run a GitHub Action that creates a container from my Dockerfile and then runs all the build code from an `entrypoint.sh` file. Here is the pertinent code from my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:alpine as jekyll

ENV env_workspace_directory=$workspace_directory

... more irrelevant code ...

RUN echo "#################################################"
RUN echo "Copy the GitHub repo to the Docker container"
RUN echo "COPY . ${env_workspace_directory}"
COPY . ${env_workspace_directory}

RUN echo "#################################################"
RUN echo "Run the entrypoint "
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Because I am using the `Remote Containers` VS Code extension, I do not want the Dockerfile to contain the `COPY . ${env_workspace_directory}` code. Instead, I only want that code to run when used as a GitHub Action.

So I guess I have two questions, with the first being ideal:

1. Is it possible to write like-type code that will copy the contents of the currently open GitHub branch (or at least the `main` branch), including all files and subfolders into the Docker container using the `entrypoint.sh` file instead? If so, what would that `entrypoint.sh` code look like?
2. Is it possible to leave the `COPY` command in the Dockerfile and make it conditional? For example "Only run the COPY command if running from a GitHub Action"?

For #1 above, I reviewed [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/how-to-copy-files-from-host-to-docker-container) article that says you can use the `docker cp` command, but I am unsure if that is (a) correct and (b) how to be sure I am using the `$workspace_directory`.

I am very new to Dockerfiles, writing shell commands, and GitHub Actions, so apologies if this question is an easy one or if more clarifications are required.

Here is the [Development repo](https://github.com/BillRaymond/agile-in-action-minima) if that is useful.

Comment: docker cp should work fine.

$workspace_directory is a pseudo-code variable in this case. If you are using bash, $PWD would be your current working directory. If you  git switched to the branch you want to be on, you can docker cp your files

```docker cp /path/to/files/fodlers/you/want/to/copy container_id_or_name:/destination/path/for/file/folder/you/want/to/copy```

I wouldn't put this in a dockerfile. Just docker cp when you bring up the container.

You can also use a docker volume. Just mount the working directory to somewhere in the container.

Comment: Thank you. Get you help me understand what that source`/path/to/files/folders/you/want/to/copy` structure is when you are acting in a GitHub Action and wanting to get all root and sub folders and files in GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Docker volume mount happens after the image is built but before the main container process is run.  So if you do something like

```bash
docker run -v "$PWD/site:/site" your-image
```

then the `entrypoint.sh` script will see the host content in the container's `/site` directory, even if something different had been `COPY`ed in the Dockerfile.

There are no conditionals or flow control in Dockerfiles, beyond shell syntax within individual `RUN` instructions.  You could in principle access a Git repository in your container process, but managing the repository location, ssh credentials, branches, uncommitted files, *etc.* can get complex.

Depending on how you're using the image, I could suggest two approaches here.

If you have a deploy-time action that uses this image in its entirety to build the site, then just leave your Dockerfile as-is.  In development use a bind mount to inject your host content; don't especially worry about skipping the image `COPY` here.

Another approach is to build the image containing the Jekyll *tool*, but to treat the site itself as *data*.  In that case you'd always run the image with a `docker run -v` or Compose `volumes:` option to inject the data.  In the Dockerfile you might create an empty directory to be safe

```bash
RUN mkdir "${env_workspace_directory}" # consider a fixed path
```

and in your entrypoint script you can verify the site exists

```bash
if [ ! -f "$env_workspace_directory/_site.yml" ]; then
  cat >&2 <<EOF
There does not seem to be a Jekyll site in $env_workspace_directory.
Please re-run this container with the site mounted.
EOF
  exit 1
fi
```