# Docker - how can I copy a file from an image to a host?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/docker-copy-file-from-container-to-host) on copying files from containers to hosts; I have a Dockerfile that fetches dependencies, compiles a build artifact from source, and runs an executable. I also want to copy the build artifact (in my case it's a `.zip` produced by `sbt dist` in '../target/`, but I think this question also applies to jars, binaries, etc.

`docker cp` works on containers, not images; do I need to start a container just to get a file out of it? In a script, I tried running `/bin/bash` in interactive mode in the background, copying the file out, and then killing the container, but this seems kludgey. Is there a better way?

On the other hand, I would like to avoid unpacking a `.tar` file after running `docker save $IMAGENAME` just to get one file out (but that seems like the simplest, if slowest, option right now).

I would use docker volumes, e.g.:

```
docker run -v hostdir:out $IMAGENAME /bin/cp/../blah.zip /out
```

but I'm running `boot2docker` in OSX and I don't know how to directly write to my mac host filesystem (read-write volumes are mounting inside my boot2docker VM, which means I can't easily share a script to extract `blah.zip` from an image with others. Thoughts?

Comment: `save` is the only option, if do not have a runnable image, e.g. an image `FROM scratch` with `COPY --from ...` lines, that does not contain e.g. `bash` and has no `ENTRYPOINT`. The reason is that `docker container create` fails on those images.

Answer (score 397):

To copy a file from an image, create a temporary container, copy the file from it and then delete it:

```
id=$(docker create image-name)
docker cp $id:path - > local-tar-file
docker rm -v $id
```

Comment: What version of docker was the `create` command added/removed (its not present in 1.01)

Comment: @ThorSummoner `docker create` was introduced in docker 1.3, https://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/

Comment: This did not work for me.  Specifically, the `docker create` command listed is insufficient for docker 16.04, requiring more arguments at minimum.

Comment: @ChrisCleeland Does it work in your case when you add `--entrypoint /` arguments to the docker create command?

Comment: This is good @IgorBukanov. I'm a semi-newbie at docker, and I was having a hard time figuring out how to view the content of an _image_ without starting a _container_. The answer - which you provided here - is, create a container, but don't start it. Thanks!

Comment: This is only method out of these that worked for me.  the --entrypoint "cp" method resulted in a file not found when it tried to copy from mount. seemed like some sort of race condition with the mount being available and the entrypoint executing as it worked if I shelled in and then executed the copy.

Comment: Definitely the right answer!!! Doesn't rely on anything inside the container... For Golang scratch images, this is the only way possible!

Comment: really useful answer but I prefer using --name param over id env var to identify the created docker container

Comment: any reason to copy to stdout and then direct it to a local file? when I did this, it dumped a bunch of control characters before and after the file's content. running it directly as `docker cp $id:path > local-tar-file` worked perfectly.

Comment: @Yonatan The main reason to save as a tar archive was to ensure that all information including ownership names are extracted and to allow to examine the archive locally before extracting it for extra safety. Plus earlier docker versions IIRC did not support or had some issues with copying a directory from the container to a local directory. But if you know the structure of your container and your docker version is not ancient one, surely you can just use docker cp $id:path local_path to extract into a local file or directory.

Comment: To be extracted with `tar -xvf <local-tar-file>`

Answer (score 122):

```
docker cp $(docker create --name tc registry.example.com/ansible-base:latest):/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa ./hacked_ssh_key && docker rm tc
```

for rhel/fedora:

```
podman cp $(podman create --name tc docker.io/alpine/curl):/usr/bin/curl ./curl && podman rm tc
```

wanted to supply a one line solution based on pure docker functionality (no bash needed)

edit: container does not even has to be run in this solution

edit2: thanks to @Jonathan Dumaine for --rm so the container will be removed after, i just never tried, because it sounded illogical to copy something from somewhere which has been already removed by the previous command, but i tried it and it works

edit3: due the comments we found out --rm is not working as expected, it does not remove the container because it never runs, so I added functionality to delete the created container afterwards(--name tc=temporary-container)

edit 4: this error appeared, seems like a bug in docker, because t is in a-z and this did not happen a few months before.

```
Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (t), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed
```

Comment: Underrated answer! It also works if you add `--rm` to the `docker create` call to leave no trace of the temporary container.

Comment: thanks i edited this, it just sounded strange to --rm it first and then copy the file from it, i thought it wouldn't work so i never tried, but now i tried and it works haha

Comment: I don't think `--rm` removes anything in this case since the container never runs

Comment: Isn't there a chance that this will remove the container before copying has completed?

Comment: no, because as roman said, the --rm does not remove anything because the container never runs

Comment: This has to be followed up with `docker rm` call to remove the container.

Comment: technically bash is still needed as `$(...)` is used

Comment: @m13r i think you got that wrong, yes bash or any shell is generally needed to execute commands, but IN the container there is no shell needed with this approach, other approaches need to have bash/sh/zsh built in to work, which is not the case for all images, images built from scratch with golang binary statically compiled as example

Comment: I think `--rm` is not doing what you want. It does not remove the container, because `--rm` only removes the container on *exit* and the container cannot exit if it doesn't start. (And if it did you couldn't copy the files from it.) So while it doesn't hurt anything here (it doesn't do anything), it's misleading. It does **not** result in the container being removed. Instead, as @Mitar said, you need to manually `docker rm` the container.

Comment: @ElliottSlaughter feel free to edit my answer, i added the --rm because of comment #1

Comment: @ElytschaSmith I could not submit the edit because the edit queue is full. I think you need to either approve or reject the other edits first. (Or we need an mod to do so. I do not have the necessary privilege level.)

Comment: i edited rm functionality..

Comment: `Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (t), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed
must specify at least one container source`

Answer (score 115):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to copy files directly from Docker images. You need to create a container first and then copy the file from the container.

However, if your image contains a `cat` command (and it will do in many cases), you can do it with a single command:

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint cat yourimage  /path/to/file > path/to/destination
```

If your image doesn't contain `cat`, simply create a container and use the `docker cp` command as suggested in Igor's answer.

Comment: Fantastic solution. Couldn't access my container since it crashed a second after launching, but needed to grab a file within it. This worked perfectly.

Comment: FWIW, when doing this it recently started breaking for me. Basically it would lose some bytes at the end. I fixed it with a sleep like so: `docker run --rm --entrypoint bash yourimage  -c 'cat /path/to/file; sleep 1' > path/to/destination`. This was docker 24.0.5.

Answer (score 52):

A much faster option is to copy the file from running container to a mounted volume:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/opt/mount --rm --entrypoint cp image:version /data/libraries.tgz /opt/mount/libraries.tgz
```

> real 0m0.446s

** VS **

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint cat image:version /data/libraries.tgz > libraries.tgz
```

> real 0m9.014s

Comment: This probably has more to do with the underlying file system performing a lazy/shallow copy of the file (think copy-on-write) in the first example, vs actually copying the bytes of the file in the second example. A useful test would be to see if `cat a >b` vs `cp a b` have similar timings as shown here. Also, if the source path and destination path reside on different file systems, then both examples will lead to a full byte-for-byte copy.

Comment: Only solution worked for me to copy a file from image. Others solutions gave stupid docker error. My docker version: `Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289`

Answer (score 23):

Parent comment already showed how to use *cat*. You could also use *tar* in a similar fashion:

```
docker run yourimage tar -c -C /my/directory subfolder | tar x
```

Comment: This answer is to copy directories instead files as the original question asks about. However, +1 because it also works with files and comes with an extra feature: permission and owner preservation. Great!

Comment: Actually, I use `docker run --rm --entrypoint tar _image_ cC _img_directory_ . | tar xvC _host_directory_`

Answer (score 14):

Another (short) answer to this problem:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/opt/mount --rm -ti image:version bash -c "cp /source/file /opt/mount/"
```

**Update** - as noted by [@Elytscha Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11797317/elytscha-smith) **this only works if your image has bash built in**

Comment: *another short answer for images containing bash executable

alpine does not per default and images built from scratch do also not

Comment: If your image does not have `bash` you can use `sh` instead.

Comment: if you use docker cp instead, it works regardless if the container has installed bash, sh, zsh or no shell

Answer (score 9):

First pull docker image using docker pull

```
docker pull <IMG>:<TAG>
```

Then, create a container using docker create command and store the container id is a variable

```
img_id=$(docker create <IMG>:<TAG>)
```

Now, run the `docker cp` command to copy folders and files from docker container to host

```
docker cp $img_id:/path/in/container /path/in/host
```

Once the files/folders are moved, delete the container using docker rm

```
docker rm -v $img_id
```

Answer (score 6):

Not a direct answer to the question details, but in general, once you pulled an image, the **image is stored on your system and so are all its files**. Depending on the storage driver of the local Docker installation, these files can usually be found in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` (requires root access). `overlay2` should be the most common storage driver nowadays, but the path may differ.

The layers associated with an image can be found using `$ docker inspect image IMAGE_NAME:TAG`, look for a `GraphDriver` attribute.
At least in my local environment, the following also works to quickly see all layers associated with an image:
`docker inspect image IMAGE_NAME:TAG | jq ".[0].GraphDriver.Data"`

In one of these `diff` directories, the wanted file can be found.
So in theory, there's no need to create a temporary container. Ofc this solution is pretty inconvenient.

Comment: Nice solution, It might be inconvenient but there are certainly use cases where you don't want to start a container. Note that this only works when you are using `overlay2` as storage driver. (But the same technique with other paths can be used for other storage drivers)

Comment: I actually learnt a little bit more about containers in the mean time and edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This was the solution I needed, because the image I'm working with has no executables in it so it can't be run because there's no command that can be run in it. It's used purely as a source for copying files, but that involves building another image to get at them. This solution was by far the quickest and easiest way to get them out for debugging.

Comment: You can use the --format flag instead of jq `podman image inspect --format "{{ .GraphDriver.Data.UpperDir }}" 9e179bacf43c`

Answer (score 4):

Update - here's a better version without the tar file:

```
$id = & docker create image-name
docker cp ${id}:path .
docker rm -v $id
```

Old answer
PowerShell variant of Igor Bukanov's answer:

```
$id = & docker create image-name
docker cp ${id}:path - > local-file.tar
docker rm -v $id
```

Answer (score 3):

You essentially had the best solution already. Have the container copy out the files for you, and then remove itself when it's complete.

This will copy the files from `/inside/container/` to your machine at `/path/to/hostdir/`.

```
docker run --rm -v /path/to/hostdir:/mnt/out "$IMAGENAME" /bin/cp -r /inside/container/ /mnt/out/
```

Comment: I love SO. People give -1 and do not explain WHY. I would like to know why this is the case.

Comment: The only annoying thing with this solution is the files on the host and up being owned by root instead of the user I am using to run the docker command. Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

If the binary is created from a custom image based on a dockerfile then:

```bash
docker build -t name-of-the-image -f custom.dockerfile .
id=$(docker create name-of-the-image)
docker cp $id:/path/to/binary-file - > binary-file
docker rm -v $id
```

The above is also an alternative to staged builds in case they are not supported  by the docker version that you use (e.g. 1.13).
You build the binary and copy it to the host and in a second step, you build the new image that copies that binary from the host.

Answer (score 0):

I am using boot2docker on MacOS. I can assure you that scripts based on "docker cp" are portable. Because any command is relayed inside boot2docker but then the binary stream is relayed back to the docker command line client running on your mac. So write operations from the docker client are executed inside the server and written back to the executing client instance!

I am sharing a backup script for docker volumes with any docker container I provide and my backup scripts are tested both on linux and MacOS with boot2docker. The backups can be easily exchanged between platforms. Basically I am executing the following command inside my script:

```
docker run --name=bckp_for_volume --rm --volumes-from jenkins_jenkins_1 -v /Users/github/jenkins/backups:/backup busybox tar cf /backup/JenkinsBackup-2015-07-09-14-26-15.tar /jenkins
```

> Runs a new busybox container and mounts the volume of my jenkins container with the name jenkins_jenkins_1. The whole volume is written to the file backups/JenkinsBackup-2015-07-09-14-26-15.tar

I have already moved archives between the linux container and my mac container without any adjustments to the backup or restore script. If this is what you want you find the whole script an tutorial here: [blacklabelops/jenkins](https://github.com/blacklabelops/jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

You could [bind](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) a local path on the host to a path on the container, and then `cp` the desired file(s) to that path at the end of your script.

```
$ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Then there is no need to copy afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the Windows command prompt:

```
for /f %i in ('docker create image_id') do set id=%i
docker cp %id%:/file/path .
docker rm -v %id%
```