# Can not add new user in docker container with mounted /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, docker, passwd, etcpasswd

### Example of the problem:

```
docker run -ti -v my_passwd:/etc/passwd -v my_shadow:/etc/shadow --rm centos
[root@681a5489f3b0 /]# useradd test # does not work !?
useradd: failure while writing changes to /etc/passwd
[root@681a5489f3b0 /]# ll /etc/passwd /etc/shadow # permission check
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 157 Oct  8 10:17 /etc/passwd
-rw-r----- 1 root root 100 Oct  7 18:02 /etc/shadow
```

The similar problem arises when using passwd:

```
[root@681a5489f3b0 /]# passwd test
Changing password for user test.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters
Retype new password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

I have tried using the ubuntu image, but the same problem arises.

I can manually edit passwd file and shadow file from within container.

#### I am getting the same problem on following two machines:

Host OS: CentOS 7 - SELinux Disabled
Docker Version: 1.8.2, build 0a8c2e3

Host OS: CoreOS 766.4.0
Docker version: 1.7.1, build df2f73d-dirty

I've also opened issue on GitHub: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16857

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's failing because `passwd` manipulates a temporary file, and then attempts to rename it to `/etc/shadow`.  This fails because `/etc/shadow` is a mountpoint -- which cannot be replaced -- which results in this error (captured using `strace`):

```
102   rename("/etc/nshadow", "/etc/shadow") = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
```

You can reproduce this trivially from the command line:

```
# cd /etc
# touch foo
# mv foo shadow
mv: cannot move 'foo' to 'shadow': Device or resource busy
```

You could work around this by mounting a directory containing `my_shadow` and `my_passwd` somewhere else, and then symlinking `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` in the container appropriately:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v $PWD/my_etc:/my_etc centos
[root@afbc739f588c /]# ln -sf /my_etc/my_passwd /etc/passwd
[root@afbc739f588c /]# ln -sf /my_etc/my_shadow /etc/shadow
[root@afbc739f588c /]# ls -l /etc/{shadow,passwd}
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Oct  8 17:48 /etc/passwd -> /my_etc/my_passwd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Oct  8 17:48 /etc/shadow -> /my_etc/my_shadow
[root@afbc739f588c /]# passwd root
Changing password for user root.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[root@afbc739f588c /]#
```

Comment: With this solution  useradd and adduser no longer work. How should this be fixed?

Comment: I've tried this and the symlink is simply removed and replaced by a copy of the shadow file in its place (in the container) so you won't get an update on the host. So if this ever worked, for debian/ubuntu its now definitely useless.

Comment: I have also tried and failed with this method, however it gave me just what I needed to make it work. Instead of symlinking /etc/{passwd,shadow} to /my_etc/, all you need to do is to copy the files back and forth: `cp /metc/* /etc` -> do your deeds -> `cp /etc/{passwd,shadow} /metc/`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today. After trying basically everything, I arrived at the unfortunate conclusion that there's no good way to make `passwd`, `useradd`, `groupadd`, etc. all happy without mounting the entire `/etc` directory. The one saving grace is that it likely won't take up too much space if you are using a minimised base (e.g. [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine), [bitnami/minideb](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/minideb)).

---

The following is a table of things I tried and why they each failed:

| Method | Problem |
| --- | --- |
| mount `/my-path` and symlink `/etc/{passwd,group,shadow,gshadow}` to `/my-path/...` | `useradd` and `groupadd` failure (presumably `userdel` and `groupdel` will fail too) |
| mount `/my-path` and hard link `/etc/{passwd,group,shadow,gshadow}` to `/my-path/...` | hard links cannot cross file system boundary |
| mount `/etc/{passwd,group,shadow,gshadow}` individually | everything fails |
| install an init system like [s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) and use a file synchronisation program | janky AF; potential race condition; inefficient; etc. |

In the end I just had to sigh and take the L and mount the entire `/etc` directory. Honestly I recommend you do the same - it's not worth my time and neither is it worth yours.

---

If you are doing this, you probably want to copy the contents of `/etc` from the image to your host before you start your container for the first time, otherwise your `/etc` will just be an empty mount. For this, you can use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31316636/5637701).

If you are using `docker-compose` or `podman-compose`, you can use [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) to temporarily mount the empty host directory into `/tmp/etc` (or anywhere else for that matter), so that it's not shadowing the real `/etc` when you perform the copy:

```yaml
services:
  my-service:
    container_name: my-container
    volumes:
      - /dir/on/host:${DIVERT_DIR}/etc
```

```bash
# I'm using podman but it's the same thing with docker

# create temporary container without shadowing /etc
DIVERT_DIR=/tmp podman-compose up --no-start

# copy /etc to host
podman cp my-container:/etc /dir/on/host

# tear down temporary container
podman rm my-container

# create and start the actual container
podman-compose up
```