# With Docker, how can I bind mount but also preserve container files?

Tags: docker

I want to use a Docker container to run a utility (specifically Terraform) using local files. In order to quickly iterate on the code (such as `my_stuff.tf`) I want to bind mount my working directory. However, I want to consider some things as relatively stable and static, such as plugins. Basically there are three ways I want things to be handled:

1. `.terraform/` is stable stuff that should exist in the container but not my host directory, but needs to be preserved even after mounting.
2. `my_stuff.tf` exists both within container (because `init` needs it) and in host dir (because I want to edit it). I want my host directory version of this to override the container version.
3. `terraform.tfstate` might not exist in either place to start with, but gets generated during running. I want it to persist in my host directory as soon as it does exist.

(and I guess a 4th category like `README.md` where I do not care whether it is there or not)

In my case, TF expects both `.terraform/` where plugins are configured and `terraform.tfstate` (one of the outputs I want to catch with my bind-mount) to be in the same directory, so I cannot just use different directories for the container-internal stuff and the bind-mounted stuff.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM plugin_source AS plugins
FROM terraform_base
COPY --from=plugins terraform-provider-X /bin/
COPY my_stuff.tf /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN /bin/terraform init
```

And my run command:

```
docker run --rm -i -t --mount source=$PWD,target=/app,type=bind my_terraform <some-tf-command>
```

Is there a slick way to make bind mounts behave how named volumes do on first initialization, as described in https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container? At present, it seems like I might have to write a little entrypoint script that symlinks the stable stuff into my work directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to do this with an old Development Weblogic container running on my computer:

1. Run the image
2. `docker cp` the directories of interest to the local disk
3. `Stop` and `kill` the container
4. Run the image again with the volume mappings.

This allowed me to get a fresh start with files from a virgin container and preserve all changes within the server.

Comment: So, applying this pattern to my scenario, I would copy the `.terraform/` directory out to my host after I build the image, so that it exists in the bind-mount?

Comment: Yes, this is how I solved it on my end. Run once to copy the directory. Delete it. Run again with volume mapping and voilá.

Comment: Ok, between your answer and https://stackoverflow.com/a/31316636/447862 I can fully automate this process! 1. build 2. create 3. cp 4. rm 5. run