# Junit report is not updated after run tests on gitlab

Tags: docker, junit, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I run automated tests on `gitlab ci` with `gitlab runner`, all works good except reports. After tests `junit` reports are not updated, always show the same pass and not pass tests even thought `cmd` show different number of passed tests.

Gitlab script:

```yaml
    stages:
      - build
      - test
    
    docker-build-master:
      image: docker:latest
      stage: build
      services:
        - docker:dind
      before_script:
        - docker login -u "xxx" -p "yyy" docker.io
      script:
        - docker build ./AutomaticTests --pull -t "dockerImage" 
        - docker image tag dockerImage xxx/dockerImage:0.0.1
        - docker push "xxx/dockerImage:0.0.1"
    
    test:
      image: docker:latest
      services:
        - docker:dind
      stage: test
      before_script:
        - docker login -u "xxx" -p "yyy" docker.io
      script: 
        - docker run "xxx/dockerImage:0.0.1"
      artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
          - AutomaticTests/bin/Release/artifacts/test-result.xml
        reports:
          junit:
            - AutomaticTests/bin/Release/artifacts/test-result.xml
```

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1
    
    COPY /publish  /AutomaticTests
    WORKDIR /AutomaticTests
    RUN apt-get update -y
    RUN apt install unzip
    RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install
    RUN curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/chromedriver_linux64.zip -o /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
    RUN unzip -o /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -d /AutomaticTests
    RUN chmod 777 /AutomaticTests
    
    CMD dotnet vstest /Parallel AutomaticTests.dll --TestAdapterPath:. --logger:"nunit;LogFilePath=..\artifacts\test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
```

Comment: What happens if you run `JUnit` locally, e.g. using command line or IDE? Is the JUnit report correct? If not, then this problem has nothing to do with gitlab/docker. Also, please provide the outputs of the junit report an what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using docker-in-docker for my gitlab pipeline. You run your tests **inside your container**. Therefore, test results are stored inside your "container-under-test". However, the gitlab-ci paths reference not the "container-under-test", but the outside container of your docker-in-docker environment.

You could try to copy the test results from the image directly to your outside container via something like this:

```
mkdir reports
docker cp $(docker create --rm DOCKER_IMAGE):/ABSOLUTE/FILEPATH/IN/DOCKER/CONTAINER reports/.
```

So, this would be something like this in your case (untested...!):

```
...

    test:
      image: docker:latest
      services:
        - docker:dind
      stage: test
      before_script:
        - docker login -u "xxx" -p "yyy" docker.io
      script: 
        - mkdir reports
        - docker cp $(docker create --rm xxx/dockerImage:0.0.1):/AutomaticTests/bin/Release/artifacts/test-result.xml reports/.
      artifacts:
        when: always
        reports:
          junit:
            - reports/test-result.xml
...
```

Also, see this post for furhter explanation on the `docker cp` command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59055906/6603778

Keep in mind, that `docker cp` requires an absolute path to the file you want to copy from your container.